# Get a Try statement to loop around until correct value obtained

Tags: python, exception, loops, try-catch

I am trying to get a user to enter a number between 1 and 4. I have code to check if the number is correct but I want the code to loop around several times until the numbers is correct. Does anyone know how to do this? The code is below:

```
def Release():        
    try:
        print 'Please select one of the following?\nCompletion = 0\nRelease ID = 1\nVersion ID = 2\nBuild ID = 3\n'
        a = int(input("Please select the type of release required: "))
        if a == 0:
            files(a)
        elif a == 1:
            files(a)
        elif a == 2:
            files(a)
        elif a == 3:
            files(a)
        else:
            raise 'incorrect'
    except 'incorrect':    
        print 'Try Again'
    except:
        print 'Error'

Release()
```

I am also getting an error about the exception I have entered:

```bash
kill.py:20: DeprecationWarning: catching of string exceptions is deprecated
  except 'incorrect':
Error
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: This is a really bad design; incorrect user input here is not really an exception at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retry after exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083987/how-to-retry-after-exception)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
def files(a):
    pass

while True:
    try:
        i = int(input('Select: '))
        if i in range(4):
            files(i)
            break
    except:    
        pass

    print '\nIncorrect input, try again'
```

Comment: @jellybean -- Thanks for this. This work's the best, all other answers are good but this code catches the user entering any other incorrect variable.

Answer (score 6):

Modern Python exceptions are classes; by using `raise 'incorrect'`, you are using a deprecated language feature called string exceptions. The [Errors and Exceptions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html) section of the Python tutorial would be a good place to start with basic exception handling in Python.

In general, exceptions are not ideal for your situation anyway—a simple `while` loop should be sufficient. Exceptions should be reserved for exceptional situations, and bad user input is not exceptional, it's expected.

The loop-based version of `Release` would look something like this:

```
def Release():
    a = None
    while a not in (0, 1, 2, 3):
        print 'Please select one of the following?\nCompletion = 0\nRelease ID = 1\nVersion ID = 2\nBuild ID = 3\n'
        try:
            a = int(input("Please select the type of release required: "))
        except ValueError:
            pass  # Could happen in face of bad user input
    files(a)
```

P.S. `a` is a bad variable name; you should probably change it to `chosen_option` or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

Your approach seems to be a very long-winded way to accomplish something fairly simple:

```
def Release() :
    while True :
        print 'Please select one of the following?\nCompletion = 0\nRelease ID = 1\nVersion ID = 2\nBuild ID = 3\n'
        a = int(input("Please select the type of release required: "))
        if 0 <= a < 4 :
            files(a)
            break
        else :
            print('Try Again')
```

Answer (score 3):

You are both throwing and catching the exception in the same simple block of code - this is not really what exception handling is about. You can do it better either by breaking out of a loop or by keeping a condition. E.g.:

```
def isNumberCorrect(x):
   return x in range(4)

def Release():
    num = None # incorrect

    while not isNumberCorrect(num):
        print 'Please select one of the following?\nCompletion = 0\nRelease ID = 1\nVersion ID = 2\nBuild ID = 3\n'
        num_str = raw_input("Please select the type of release required: ")

        try:
            num = int(num_str)
        except ValueError:
            num = None

        if not isNumberCorrect(num):
            print 'Incorrect!'

     # work with num here; it's guaranteed to be correct.

if __name__ == '__main__':
  try:
    Release()
  except:
    print 'Error!'
```

**EDIT:** Added error checking in the int parsing.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using exceptions you could do something like this:

```
...
a = raw_input("Please select the type of release required:")
while a not in ['0','1','2','3']: a = raw_input("Try again: ")
files(int(a))
...
```

Comment: That's true. Not usable as such

Answer (score 2):

```
def Release():
    while 1:
        print """Please select one of the following?
                 Completion = 0
                 Release ID = 1
                 Version ID = 2
                 Build ID = 3
                 Exit = 4 """            
        try:
             a = int(raw_input("Please select the type of release required: "))
        except Exception,e:
             print e
        else:
             if a==4: return 0
             files(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to check if the input is a **number**:
For me, the working solution in my project was:

```
while True:
    number1 = input("Enter a number: ")
    try:
        n1 = int(number1)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("It has to be a number!")

# then proceed with your code using this number
```