# Try/except in a list of functions

Tags: python

I have a list of functions. I would like to loop through the list and try if one of the functions goes well without error. I tried this:

```
list_functions = [func1(var), func2(var)]

for function in list_functions:
    try:
        function
    except:
        pass
    else:
        break

else:
    raise Exception("No function succeeded.")
```

But my code tries only the `func1` and then fails. How can I fix my code, please?

This question did not help me: [Get a Try statement to loop around until correct value obtained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244270/get-a-try-statement-to-loop-around-until-correct-value-obtained/2244307)

Comment: "tries only the func1 and then falls" - because the function is called outside the `try...except` block. Your list of functions is a list of the results of calling your functions.

Comment: Your code is not doing what you think. Your functions are executed when you call them here: `list_functions = [func1(var), func2(var)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, please provide (and look at! ;)) the full traceback when you get an error. You would see that your `func1` is not called within your `try: except:` block, but when you create your `list_functions`. It will contain the result of the calls to `func1`, `func2`, which are evaluated at that time. And since `func1` returns an error, the execution stops at that point.

To fix this: you have to call your functions within the try: except: block, for example like this:

```
list_functions = [func1, func2]

for function in list_functions:
    try:
        function(var)
    except Exception as exc:
        pass
    else:
        break
else:
    raise Exception("No function succeeded.")
```

It might be a little more complex if you have variable arguments to pass to each of your methods, but that can be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you called every function when defining your `list_functions` list. Try separating the parameters into a separate list, and call each function in the `for` loop:

```
list_functions = [func1, func2]
list_vars = [var1, var2]
for function, var in zip(list_functions, list_vars):
    try:
        function(var)
    except:
        pass
    else:
        break
else:
    raise Exception("No function succeeded.")
```

If the parameter remains the same for every function, then the `zip()` method won't be necessary anymore, as well as the separate list of variables. Just:

```
list_functions = [func1, func2]

for function in list_functions:
    try:
        function(var)
    except:
        pass
    else:
        break

else:
    raise Exception("No function succeeded.")
```