# How to run again same method of class in case of Exception

Tags: python, django, multithreading

So I have threads class to update entries in DB. 
Algo is following:
1. Entries being put in queue
2. TableUpdater threads take entries from queue and insert into DB
There are cases when queue is empty and I want threads to check one more time and try to do insert again.

```
class TableUpdater(threading.Thread):

 def __init__(self, import_queue):
    self.import_queue = import_queue
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)

 def run(self):
     try:
        entry = self.import_queue.get()
        do_something_with_entry()
     except Queue.Empty:
          # Here I want thread to check queue one more
          # time and if it is not empty then execute above try block again
```

So how can I do so without copypasting those try block? I need to tell thread to try execute same block of code but only 1 more time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enclose the try except block inside a while True loop and break when you want.

Similar question was answered here: [How to retry after exception in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083987/how-to-retry-after-exception-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer a constant number of trials instead of a `while True` loop because you can find yourself in an infinite loop if the `Queue.Empty` error persists. It would also be nice to separate the queue.get() part (where you expect the error) from the possibly long entry processing part. I recommend reorganizing your code like this:

```
 def getEntry(self,trials=1):
    for i in range(trials):
        try:
           return self.import_queue.get()

        except Queue.Empty:
           continue   # move to next trial 

    raise Queue.Empty   # raise error if not returned after given number of trials 


 def run(self):
     entry = self.getEntry(trials=2)
     do_something_with_entry()
```

UPDATE

To fire as long as queue is not empty, you can call run() in a while loop and break on error:

```
 def runUntilNotEmpty(self):
     while True:
           try:
                self.run()
           except Queue.Empty:
                break
```

Breaking a `while True` loop on error is much better than breaking on success, because 
1) You will definitely not run into an infinite loop, because you cannot have an infinite queue.
2) You don't just vanish your error, but you can manage it somehow (raise warnings etc.).

Comment: Doesn't that code mean that `queue.get()` will run only twice? I need to code be fired as long as queue is not empty and then 1 more time again

Comment: In your sample code, queue.get() runs only once. I updated my answer to perform as-long-as-queue-is-not-empty runs.