# How to continue loop after catching exception

Tags: python

The below code produces exception while handling non `int` values but it doesn't continue the loop but rather comes out from the loop raising error. My intention is to provide the value of 0 for exception cases.

**Sample Input:**

```
Common Ruby Errors 45min
Rails for Python Developers lightning
```

**Code:**

```
class TimeNotProvidedError(Exception):
    pass

def extract_input():
    lines = []
    __tracks = {}

    try:
        lines = [line.strip() for line in open('test.txt')]
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        print("File Not Found", e)

    for line in lines:
        title, minutes = line.rsplit(maxsplit=1)
        minutes = int(minutes[:-3])
        try:
            __tracks[title] = minutes
        except TimeNotProvidedError:
            __tracks[title] = 0
    return __tracks

print(extract_input())
```

**Traceback:**

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'lightn'
```

Comment: can you add a couple of lines from test.txt

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083987/how-to-retry-after-exception-in-python  -  you might try using 'continue'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting the error when converting to `int` with this line: `minutes = int(minutes[:-3])`. That line isn't in the `try` block, so the exception isn't caught. Move that line inside the `try` block, and you'll get the behavior you wanted.

Furthermore, the exception you're catching is `TimeNotProvidedError`, which isn't what `int` throws when a conversion fails. Instead, it throws `ValueError`, so that's the exception type you need to catch.

---

The mere act of assigning to `__tracks[title]` is unlikely to cause an exception, and if it *does*, re-trying with another assignment probably won't work anyway. What you probably want in your loop is this:

```
title, minutes = line.rsplit(maxsplit=1)
try:
    minutes = int(minutes[:-3])
except ValueError:
    minutes = 0
__tracks[title] = minutes
```