# python os.path.exists reports False when files is there

Tags: python, macos, os.path

Hi have an application which is sometimes reporting that a file does not exist even when it does, I am using os.path.exists and the file is on a mounted network share. I am on OSX Yosemite, python 2.7.9 and I have access rights to the file. Here's the weird thing. The first command below reports `False`, I then run it again but change one of the characters in the file name to lowercase (`TestVendorid_VerifyLog.txt`), run it again and it reports `True`! Then run it again with the upper case again (`TestVendorId_VerifyLog.txt`) and it reports `True`! What is going on? This is quite consistent, in that it returns `True` most of the time, but then all of a sudden return `False`, then I can repeat the below exercise.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.exists("/Volumes/platform-deliveries-103_1/TEST/TestVendorId.itmsp/TestVendorId_VerifyLog.txt")
False
>>> os.path.exists("/Volumes/platform-deliveries-103_1/TEST/TestVendorId.itmsp/TestVendorid_VerifyLog.txt")
True
>>> os.path.exists("/Volumes/platform-deliveries-103_1/TEST/TestVendorId.itmsp/TestVendorId_VerifyLog.txt")
True
>>>
```

UPDATE 1:

When it is reporting `True`, I ran this:

```
>>> os.stat("/Volumes/platform-deliveries-103_1/TEST/TestVendorId.itmsp/TestVendorId_VerifyLog.txt")
posix.stat_result(st_mode=33216, st_ino=5351561660274954203, st_dev=771751953L, st_nlink=1, st_uid=504, st_gid=20, st_size=38552, st_atime=1428492003, st_mtime=1428589374, st_ctime=1428589374)
```

UPDATE 2:

OK, I can now repeat this and it is definitely a cache thing. I delete the file TestVendorId_VerifyLog.txt on my local Mac, then recreate the file on another workstation (this file is on a network share) I then get False on my Mac. If I change a letter in the file name of the os.path.exists command, it seems to make os.path.exists take a harder look for the file and finds it. So what I need is a 'Refresh Finder' command in python just prior to running the command.

Comment: Are you running on a file system that is case sensitive? A different case is a different file. Linux is case sensitive.

Comment: But, 2nd and 3rd os.path.exists both pass True!

Comment: Which file is really on your filesystem? Is it case sensitive? I agree its a problem in either case, but we still want to know to help understand the problem.

Comment: The file is actually uppercase, TestVendorId_VerifyLog.txt

Comment: Maybe the problem isn't fixed by changing the case, but in running the command twice? Try running the exact function twice (don't change case) to see.

Comment: Ran it 5 times in a row, False every-time, change a case of one of the letters and bingo, True. It is definitely a cache thing on Mac. I will update the question with my findings.

Comment: The default OSX filesystems are case sensitive.

Comment: Is there a more reliable way of checking if a file exists?

Comment: Same problem, we should maybe try again for X times: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2083996/1486850

Answer (score 3):

`os.path.exists` returns `False` when an `OSError` is happening while it tries to stat the file. The exception is handled and therefor masked.

You should try to run `os.stat(filename)` to see if that gives further information on the problem.

Comment: So helpful - thank you. Really annoying that the error does not show up when using `os.path.exists()`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is not a `\n` or any other 'invisible' character anywhere in your filename.

Edit: After a few hours digging on a similar problem of my own, I realized the problem was wrong permission for the directory where my target file was in. Make sure you `ls -l` on your directory to check whether the user you are using has the proper permission.