# Python os.pathislink, exists and isdir dont work

Tags: python, linux

```
amd_path = '/sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_b10/'
amd_gpu = os.path.islink(amd_path)
```

On this path, the script always shows false whether it uses exist, islink, isdir shows false, can anyone help?
Unfortunately, my research did not help me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it actually does not exist ?

```py
>>> os.path.exists("/does-not-exist")
False
>>> os.path.islink("/does-not-exist")
False
>>> os.path.isdir("/does-not-exist")
False
```

Comment: Unfortunately, but the path exists, but python has a problem with this particular folder, because if it uses the path '/ sys / class / backlight /' it shows true, the problem only arises when you want to use it on the path '/ sys / class / backlight / amdgpu_b10 / '
On the other hand, the command line in linux is able to easily point to this folder, open it, etc.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/29541925/11384184 ?