# Is there any elegant way to write a "keep `try` until success" block in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

In my program, I use lots of blocks like this:

```
while True:

    try:
        DO_SOMETHING()
        break

    except:
        pass
```

Such that I can "keep trying until success". But this seems not Pythonic. Is there any elegant way to do this?

Comment: Why it doesn't seem pythonic? Its looks perfectly okay to me, except for the `except: pass` part.

Comment: Maybe you could make it a decorator?

Comment: @tobias_k How to make it a decorator? If it's really possible it would be the best solution here, in my opinion.

Comment: @dlask, as a similar question was found by Martijn Pieters, there is a package for this: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/retrying

Comment: Well, I just wanted to post this as an answer, but now I can't. Anyway, seems like something similar does already exist. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25912659/1639625) on the duplicate question.

Comment: You can put your code in a function with DO_SOMETHING as an argument (and probably *pargs et **kargs to pass along the arguments).

Comment: depending on what it is, a callback might also be a decent option.  they work well for asynchronous situations and most of the time would be non-blocking. the general idea is that instead of polling forever until something happens, a callback function is attached to an action of some sort.  when that actions response comes back in, the function is fired.  such a function could even be recursive, ie firing itself.