# Unable to scrape a particular site using python, urllib2

Tags: python-2.7, runtime-error, urllib2

I am using urllib for extracting the web page, and it doesn't seem to work with the site of [zomato](https://www.zomato.com/kolkata).It works with several other sites that I tried. I have tried disabling my firewall, antivirus, and wrap the urlopen line in try catch as I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315388/python-web-scraping-error-10060). I have tried using codes from the internet that seem to work fine, but I get an error message,

> v = self._sslobj.read(len or 1024)
>   socket.error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

What can be the possible reasons?

Here is the simple code for it.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def extract_link(url):            
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()                    
    return BeautifulSoup(page)

def main():
    link = 'https://www.zomato.com/kolkata'
    soup=extract_link(link)
    print soup.prettify()

if __name__== '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since zomato.com is a dynamic website and relies heavily on Javascript or AJAX to fill in its content, you need a browser in order to get that content. On top of that, zomato filters out requests which it sees as being made by bots. So, for these reasons, I would recommend you to use Selenium as it doesn't simulate a browser session, it is a browser session. Writing for selenium is basically writing a set of actions and feeding them to a browser (usually Firefox, but it can work with others). You could also use PhantomJs as an alternative since you are working with python.

Here is a little bit of help in setting up selenium and replicating your above code.

1. Download chromedriver.exe from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.25/
2. Then extract this .exe file into "Chrome Driver" folder.
3. Then cut and paste the folder containing the file into your C drive.
4. Now, do `pip install selenium.`

**Then run this code**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Chrome Driver\chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.zomato.com/kolkata")
time.sleep(3)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

body = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body")))
print(body.text)
```

**This is the output you will get :**

```
We're Hiring!
Order Food Online!
Log in
Find the best restaurants, cafés, and bars in Kolkata
Kolkata
Search
Collections
Explore curated lists of top restaurants, cafes, pubs, and bars in and around Kolkata, based on trends
Trending this week
The most popular restaurants in town this week
New restaurants you probably haven't tried yet
The best new places in town
Happy hours
Great deals on booze. Happy hours indeed
Hookah bars
Great places to enjoy flavored Hookah.
All collections in Kolkata
Order Food Online
From the best restaurants delivering to your doorstep
Enter your delivery location
Detect
Order Food Online!
Get 15% off (up to Rs. 100) on your first order with the code EATIN when you pay online.
Quick Searches
Discover restaurants by type of meal
Delivery
Breakfast
Lunch
Dinner
Drinks & Nightlife
Cafés
Pocket-Friendly Delivery
Desserts & Bakes
Popular localities in and around Kolkata
Explore restaurants, bars, and cafés by locality
Park Street Area (111 places)
Sector 5, Salt Lake (102 places)
Ballygunge (154 places)
Sector 1, Salt Lake (167 places)
Rajarhat New Town (212 places)
Southern Avenue (86 places)
Elgin (81 places)
Prince Anwar Shah Road (108 places)
Kankurgachi (116 places)
Kasba (118 places)
Camac Street Area (61 places)
Gariahat (62 places)
Park Circus Area (80 places)
Desapriya Park (61 places)
New Market Area (105 places)
Behala (136 places)
Hindustan Park (30 places)
Hatibagan (70 places)
Sector 3, Salt Lake (83 places)
Esplanade (64 places)
Jadavpur (91 places)
Golpark (37 places)
Bhawanipur (100 places)
Science City Area (19 places)
Theatre Road (47 places)
Shyam Bazar (54 places)
Garia (108 places)
Tangra (32 places)
Nagerbazar (60 places)
Tollygunge (110 places)
Top Reviewers in Kolkata
Pamela Nandi
446 Reviews , 245 Followers
Follow
Dipyaman Basu
883 Reviews , 5854 Followers
Follow
Anusreea Paul
613 Reviews , 2114 Followers
Follow
Krishanu Das
832 Reviews , 1599 Followers
Follow
Priyabrataa Ganguly
536 Reviews , 683 Followers
Follow
Reviewers leaderboard »
Top Photographers in Kolkata
Avijit Biswas
698 Reviews , 1381 Followers
Follow
Krishanu Das
832 Reviews , 1599 Followers
Follow
Mani
153 Reviews , 4473 Followers
Follow
Anusreea Paul
613 Reviews , 2114 Followers
Follow
Anamitraa Chakraborty
610 Reviews , 1255 Followers
Follow
Photographers leaderboard »
Top Bloggers in Kolkata
Arghya Deep
137 Reviews , 3498 Followers
Follow
Subham Ghosh
208 Reviews , 6497 Followers
Follow
Snehasis
230 Reviews , 929 Followers
Follow
Koninika De
356 Reviews , 4695 Followers
Follow
Dipyaman Basu
883 Reviews , 5854 Followers
Follow
Bloggers leaderboard»
Looking for the Food Feed? Get the app!
Follow foodies to see their reviews and photos in your Feed, and discover great new restaurants!
We'll send you a link, open it on your phone to download the app
 Text App Link 
OR
Email App Link
23
COUNTRIES
1.2M
RESTAURANTS
80M
FOODIES EVERY MONTH
30M
PHOTOS
10M
REVIEWS
18M
BOOKMARKS
About Careers Culture Mobile Apps Businesses Developers Blog Community Contact
English
Businesses
Add a Restaurant
Claim your Listing
Business App
Restaurant Widgets
Guidelines
Business Blog
Advertise
Book
Order
Base
Whitelabel
Countries
Australia
Brasil
Canada
Chile
Czech Republic
India
Indonesia
Ireland
Italy
Lebanon
Malaysia
New Zealand
Philippines
Poland
Portugal
Qatar
Slovakia
South Africa
Sri Lanka
Turkey
UAE
United Kingdom
United States
Privacy Terms Code of Conduct API Policy CSR Security Sitemap
By continuing past this page, you agree to our Terms of Service, Cookie Policy, Privacy Policy and Content Policies. All trademarks are properties of their respective owners. © 2008-2016 - Zomato™ Media Pvt Ltd. All rights reserved.
```