# Recording youtube live stream to file in python

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

I want to record youtube live stream and save it to file using python.

I tried with pytube library but it probably works for videos, not for live streams.

I want to record stream and save it to file with video format as avi or something like this.

Answer (score 3):

Modification based on @wownis 's answer.
(I tried that answer, however, it doesn't work.)

```
# pip install urllib
# pip install m3u8
# pip install streamlink
import urllib
import m3u8
import streamlink


def get_stream(url):
    """
    Get upload chunk url
    """
    streams = streamlink.streams(url)
    stream_url = streams["best"]

    m3u8_obj = m3u8.load(stream_url.args['url'])
    return m3u8_obj.segments[0]


def dl_stream(url, filename, chunks):
    """
    Download each chunks
    """
    pre_time_stamp = 0
    for i in range(chunks+1):
        stream_segment = get_stream(url)
        cur_time_stamp = \
            stream_segment.program_date_time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

        if pre_time_stamp == cur_time_stamp:
            pass
        else:
            print(cur_time_stamp)
            file = open(filename + '_' + str(cur_time_stamp) + '.ts', 'ab+')
            with urllib.request.urlopen(stream_segment.uri) as response:
                html = response.read()
                file.write(html)
            pre_time_stamp = cur_time_stamp


url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2U3JnFbD-es"
dl_stream(url, "live", 15)
```

Output like this:

```
./
live_20200713-103739.ts   
live_20200713-103744.ts   
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution and i put my code in python:

```
import urllib
import m3u8
import streamlink


def record_stream(url,filename,iterations):
    last_part = 0
    for i in range(iterations+1):

        streams = streamlink.streams(url)
        stream_url = streams["best"]
        print(stream_url.args['url'])

        m3u8_obj = m3u8.load(stream_url.args['url'])

        previous_part_time = last_part
        last_part = m3u8_obj.segments[-1].program_date_time

        if i >= 1:
         for j in range(1, len(m3u8_obj.segments)):
            if m3u8_obj.segments[-j].program_date_time == previous_part_time:
               break

         print(j)

         file = open(filename + ".ts", "ab+")
         for i in range(j-1,0,-1):
            with urllib.request.urlopen(m3u8_obj.segments[-i].uri) as response:
               html = response.read()
               file.write(html)


url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BgKGctL0u1U"
record_stream(url,"file",10)
```

10 means 10 iterations if chunks have 2s it means that records 20s of stream