# I want to process a live stream from youtube with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, video, youtube

I am posting this while using a translation.

I would like to use a live stream on YouTube to action recognition.
Action recognition

https://github.com/felixchenfy/Realtime-Action-Recognition

Read Youtube live stream with opencv

[How to read Youtube live stream using openCV python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43032163/how-to-read-youtube-live-stream-using-opencv-python)

Youtube URL

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DjdUEyjx8GM

We have programmed it with reference to the above.The program runs normally for a few hours, but after 4 or 5 hours, I get an error saying that communication from the remote host has been lost.Checking the youtube video, the delivery does not seem to be interrupted.

A partial code for videocapture can be found here.

```
url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DjdUEyjx8GM"
video = pafy.new(url)
best = video.getbest(preftype="mp4")

class ReadFromVideo(object):
    def __init__(self, video_path, sample_interval=1):
        ''' A video reader class for reading video frames from video.
        Arguments:
            video_path
            sample_interval {int}: sample every kth image.
        '''        assert isinstance(sample_interval, int) and sample_interval >= 1
        self.cnt_imgs = 0
        self._is_stoped = False
        self._video = cv2.VideoCapture(best.url)
        ret, image = self._video.read()
        ret, image2 = self._video2.read()
        self._next_image = image
        self._next_image2 = image2
        self._sample_interval = sample_interval
        self._fps = self.get_fps()
        if not self._fps >= 0.0001:
            import warnings
            warnings.warn("Invalid fps of video: {}".format(video_path))

    def has_image(self):
        return self._next_image is not None

    def get_curr_video_time(self):
        return 1.0 / self._fps * self.cnt_imgs

    def read_image(self):
        image = self._next_image
        image2 = self._next_image2
        for i in range(self._sample_interval):
            if self._video.isOpened():
                ret, frame = self._video.read()
                self._next_image = frame
                ret, frame2 = self._video2.read()
                self._next_image2 = frame2
            else:
                self._next_image = None
                self._next_image2 = None
                break
        self.cnt_imgs += 1
        return image, image2

    def stop(self):
        self._video.release()
        self._video2.release()
        self._is_stoped = True

    def __del__(self):
        if not self._is_stoped:
            self.stop()

    def get_fps(self):

        # Find OpenCV version
        (major_ver, minor_ver, subminor_ver) = (cv2.__version__).split('.')

        # With webcam get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS) does not work.
        # Let's see for ourselves.

        # Get video properties
        if int(major_ver) < 3:
            fps = self._video.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
        else:
            fps = self._video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
        return fps
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

'''
Test action recognition on
(1) a video, (2) a folder of images, (3) or web camera.

Input:
    model: model/trained_classifier.pickle

Output:
    result video:    output/${video_name}/video.avi
    result skeleton: output/${video_name}/skeleton_res/XXXXX.txt
    visualization by cv2.imshow() in img_displayer
'''


The entire source code is here
'''
Example of usage:

(1) Test on video file:
python src/s5_test.py \
    --model_path model/trained_classifier.pickle \
    --data_type video \
    --data_path data_test/exercise.avi \
    --output_folder output
    
(2) Test on a folder of images:
python src/s5_test.py \
    --model_path model/trained_classifier.pickle \
    --data_type folder \
    --data_path data_test/apple/ \
    --output_folder output

(3) Test on web camera:
python src/s5_test.py \
    --model_path model/trained_classifier.pickle \
    --data_type webcam \
    --data_path 0 \
    --output_folder output

if True:  # Include project path
    import sys
    import os
    ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+"/../"
    CURR_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+"/"
    sys.path.append(ROOT)

    import utils.lib_images_io as lib_images_io
    import utils.lib_plot as lib_plot
    import utils.lib_commons as lib_commons
    from utils.lib_openpose import SkeletonDetector
    from utils.lib_tracker import Tracker
    from utils.lib_tracker import Tracker
    from utils.lib_classifier import ClassifierOnlineTest
    from utils.lib_classifier import *  # Import all sklearn related libraries


def par(path):  # Pre-Append ROOT to the path if it's not absolute
    return ROOT + path if (path and path[0] != "/") else path


# -- Command-line input


def get_command_line_arguments():

    def parse_args():
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
            description="Test action recognition on \n"
            "(1) a video, (2) a folder of images, (3) or web camera.")
        parser.add_argument("-m", "--model_path", required=False,
                            default='model/trained_classifier.pickle')
        parser.add_argument("-t", "--data_type", required=False, default='webcam',
                            choices=["video", "folder", "webcam"])
        parser.add_argument("-p", "--data_path", required=False, default="",
                            help="path to a video file, or images folder, or webcam. \n"
                            "For video and folder, the path should be "
                            "absolute or relative to this project's root. "
                            "For webcam, either input an index or device name. ")
        parser.add_argument("-o", "--output_folder", required=False, default='output/',
                            help="Which folder to save result to.")

        args = parser.parse_args()
        return args
    args = parse_args()
    if args.data_type != "webcam" and args.data_path and args.data_path[0] != "/":
        # If the path is not absolute, then its relative to the ROOT.
        args.data_path = ROOT + args.data_path
    return args


def get_dst_folder_name(src_data_type, src_data_path):
    ''' Compute a output folder name based on data_type and data_path.
        The final output of this script looks like this:
            DST_FOLDER/folder_name/vidoe.avi
            DST_FOLDER/folder_name/skeletons/XXXXX.txt
    '''

    assert(src_data_type in ["video", "folder", "webcam"])

    if src_data_type == "video":  # /root/data/video.avi --> video
        folder_name = str("video")

    elif src_data_type == "folder":  # /root/data/video/ --> video
        folder_name = src_data_path.rstrip("/").split("/")[-1]

    elif src_data_type == "webcam":
        # month-day-hour-minute-seconds, e.g.: 02-26-15-51-12
        folder_name = lib_commons.get_time_string()

    return folder_name


args = get_command_line_arguments()

SRC_DATA_TYPE = args.data_type
SRC_DATA_PATH = args.data_path
SRC_MODEL_PATH = args.model_path

DST_FOLDER_NAME = get_dst_folder_name(SRC_DATA_TYPE, SRC_DATA_PATH)

# -- Settings

cfg_all = lib_commons.read_yaml(ROOT + "config/config.yaml")
cfg = cfg_all["s5_test.py"]

CLASSES = np.array(cfg_all["classes"])
SKELETON_FILENAME_FORMAT = cfg_all["skeleton_filename_format"]

# Action recognition: number of frames used to extract features.
WINDOW_SIZE = int(cfg_all["features"]["window_size"])


# Output folder
DST_FOLDER = args.output_folder + "/" + DST_FOLDER_NAME + "/"
DST_SKELETON_FOLDER_NAME = cfg["output"]["skeleton_folder_name"]
DST_VIDEO_NAME = cfg["output"]["video_name"]
# framerate of output video.avi
DST_VIDEO_FPS = float(cfg["output"]["video_fps"])

# writer
fmt = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V')
fps = 10.0
size = (800, 480)
writer = cv2.VideoWriter('outtest.mp4', fmt, fps, size)

backup_time = 3600  # sec
time = 0  # init

now = datetime.datetime.now()
s_now = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
back_up = cv2.VideoWriter(f'{s_now}.mp4',fmt, fps, size)

# Video setttings
# If data_type is webcam, set the max frame rate.
SRC_WEBCAM_MAX_FPS = float(cfg["settings"]["source"]
                           ["webcam_max_framerate"])

# If data_type is video, set the sampling interval.
# For example, if it's 3, then the video will be read 3 times faster.
SRC_VIDEO_SAMPLE_INTERVAL = int(cfg["settings"]["source"]
                                ["video_sample_interval"])

# Openpose settings
OPENPOSE_MODEL = cfg["settings"]["openpose"]["model"]
OPENPOSE_IMG_SIZE = cfg["settings"]["openpose"]["img_size"]

# Display settings
img_disp_desired_rows = int(cfg["settings"]["display"]["desired_rows"])

# -- Function


def select_images_loader(src_data_type, src_data_path):
    if src_data_type == "video":
        images_loader = lib_images_io.ReadFromVideo(
            src_data_path,
            sample_interval=SRC_VIDEO_SAMPLE_INTERVAL)

    elif src_data_type == "folder":
        images_loader = lib_images_io.ReadFromFolder(
            folder_path=src_data_path)

    elif src_data_type == "webcam":
        if src_data_path == "":
            webcam_idx = 0
        elif src_data_path.isdigit():
            webcam_idx = int(src_data_path)
        else:
            webcam_idx = src_data_path
        images_loader = lib_images_io.ReadFromWebcam(
            SRC_WEBCAM_MAX_FPS, webcam_idx)
    return images_loader


class MultiPersonClassifier(object):
    ''' This is a wrapper around ClassifierOnlineTest
        for recognizing actions of multiple people.
    '''

    def __init__(self, model_path, classes):

        self.dict_id2clf = {}  # human id -> classifier of this person

        # Define a function for creating classifier for new people.
        self._create_classifier = lambda human_id: ClassifierOnlineTest(
            model_path, classes, WINDOW_SIZE, human_id)

    def classify(self, dict_id2skeleton):
        ''' Classify the action type of each skeleton in dict_id2skeleton '''

        # Clear people not in view
        old_ids = set(self.dict_id2clf)
        cur_ids = set(dict_id2skeleton)
        humans_not_in_view = list(old_ids - cur_ids)
        for human in humans_not_in_view:
            del self.dict_id2clf[human]

        # Predict each person's action
        id2label = {}
        for id, skeleton in dict_id2skeleton.items():

            if id not in self.dict_id2clf:  # add this new person
                self.dict_id2clf[id] = self._create_classifier(id)

            classifier = self.dict_id2clf[id]
            id2label[id] = classifier.predict(skeleton)  # predict label
            # print("\n\nPredicting label for human{}".format(id))
            # print("  skeleton: {}".format(skeleton))
            # print("  label: {}".format(id2label[id]))

        return id2label

    def get_classifier(self, id):
        ''' Get the classifier based on the person id.
        Arguments:
            id {int or "min"}
        '''
        if len(self.dict_id2clf) == 0:
            return None
        if id == 'min':
            id = min(self.dict_id2clf.keys())
        return self.dict_id2clf[id]


def remove_skeletons_with_few_joints(skeletons):
    ''' Remove bad skeletons before sending to the tracker '''
    good_skeletons = []
    for skeleton in skeletons:
        px = skeleton[2:2+13*2:2]
        py = skeleton[3:2+13*2:2]
        num_valid_joints = len([x for x in px if x != 0])
        num_leg_joints = len([x for x in px[-6:] if x != 0])
        total_size = max(py) - min(py)
        # !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        # IF JOINTS ARE MISSING, TRY CHANGING THESE VALUES:
        # !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        if num_valid_joints >= 5 and total_size >= 0.1 and num_leg_joints >= 0:
            # add this skeleton only when all requirements are satisfied
            good_skeletons.append(skeleton)
    return good_skeletons


def draw_result_img(img_disp, ith_img, humans, dict_id2skeleton,
                    skeleton_detector, multiperson_classifier):
    ''' Draw skeletons, labels, and prediction scores onto image for display '''

    # Resize to a proper size for display
    r, c = img_disp.shape[0:2]
    desired_cols = int(1.0 * c * (img_disp_desired_rows / r))
    img_disp = cv2.resize(img_disp,
                          dsize=(desired_cols, img_disp_desired_rows))

    # Draw all people's skeleton
    skeleton_detector.draw(img_disp, humans)

    # Draw bounding box and label of each person
    if len(dict_id2skeleton):
        for id, label in dict_id2label.items():
            skeleton = dict_id2skeleton[id]
            # scale the y data back to original
            skeleton[1::2] = skeleton[1::2] / scale_h
            # print("Drawing skeleton: ", dict_id2skeleton[id], "with label:", label, ".")
            lib_plot.draw_action_result(img_disp, id, skeleton, label)

    # Add blank to the left for displaying prediction scores of each class
    img_disp = lib_plot.add_white_region_to_left_of_image(img_disp)

    cv2.putText(img_disp, "Frame:" + str(ith_img),
                (20, 20), fontScale=1.5, fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,
                color=(0, 0, 0), thickness=2)

    # Draw predicting score for only 1 person
    if len(dict_id2skeleton):
        classifier_of_a_person = multiperson_classifier.get_classifier(
            id='min')
        classifier_of_a_person.draw_scores_onto_image(img_disp)
    return img_disp

    # Time Display
    cv2.putText(img2_disp, str(now_time.isoformat(timespec='seconds')),
                (20, 20), fontScale=1.5, fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,
                color=(0, 0, 0), thickness=2)

    # Draw predicting score for only 1 person
    if len(dict2_id2skeleton):
        classifier_of_a_person = multiperson_classifier.get_classifier(
            id='min')
        classifier_of_a_person.draw_scores_onto_image(img2_disp)
    return img2_disp

def get_the_skeleton_data_to_save_to_disk(dict_id2skeleton):
    '''
    In each image, for each skeleton, save the:
        human_id, label, and the skeleton positions of length 18*2.
    So the total length per row is 2+36=38
    '''
    skels_to_save = []
    for human_id in dict_id2skeleton.keys():
        label = dict_id2label[human_id]
        skeleton = dict_id2skeleton[human_id]
        skels_to_save.append([[human_id, label] + skeleton.tolist()])
    return skels_to_save


# -- Main
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # -- Detector, tracker, classifier

    skeleton_detector = SkeletonDetector(OPENPOSE_MODEL, OPENPOSE_IMG_SIZE)

    multiperson_tracker = Tracker()

    multiperson_classifier = MultiPersonClassifier(SRC_MODEL_PATH, CLASSES)

    # -- Image reader and displayer
    images_loader = select_images_loader(SRC_DATA_TYPE, SRC_DATA_PATH)
    img_displayer = lib_images_io.ImageDisplayer()

    # -- Init output

    # output folder
    os.makedirs(DST_FOLDER, exist_ok=True)
    os.makedirs(DST_FOLDER + DST_SKELETON_FOLDER_NAME, exist_ok=True)
    
    # -- Read images and process
    try:
        ith_img = -1
        while images_loader.has_image():

            # Timer
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            now_time = now.time()

            # -- Read image
            #img = images_loader.read_image()
            img = images_loader.read_image()
            ith_img += 1
            img_disp = img.copy()
            # print(f"\nProcessing {ith_img}th image ...")

            # -- Detect skeletons
            humans = skeleton_detector.detect(img)
            skeletons, scale_h = skeleton_detector.humans_to_skels_list(humans)
)
            skeletons = remove_skeletons_with_few_joints(skeletons)

            # -- Track people
            dict_id2skeleton = multiperson_tracker.track(skeletons)
            
            # -- Log & Recognize action of each person
            log.append(str(now_time))

            if len(dict_id2skeleton):
                dict_id2label = multiperson_classifier.classify(
                    dict_id2skeleton)

            # -- Draw
            img_disp = draw_result_img(img_disp, ith_img, humans, dict_id2skeleton, skeleton_detector, multiperson_classifier)

            # Print label of a person
            if len(dict_id2skeleton):
                min_id = min(dict_id2skeleton.keys())
                # print("prediced label is :", dict_id2label[min_id])

            # -- Display image, and write to video.avi
            # video writer

            if time >= backup_time*fps:
                back_up.release()
                now = datetime.datetime.now()
                s_now = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
                back_up = cv2.VideoWriter(f'{s_now}.mp4', fmt, fps, size)
                time = 0
            time += 1

            writer.write(img_disp)
            back_up.write(img_disp)
            img_displayer.display(img_disp, wait_key_ms=1)

            # -- Get skeleton data and save to file
            skels_to_save = get_the_skeleton_data_to_save_to_disk(dict_id2skeleton)
            lib_commons.save_listlist(DST_FOLDER + DST_SKELETON_FOLDER_NAME +SKELETON_FILENAME_FORMAT.format(ith_img),skels_to_save)

            if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
                break

    finally:
        writer.release()
        back_up.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: A Youtube link expires after a few hours. Try re-doing the request to get a new URL (all that `video = pafy.new(url)` etc). You might also have to re-init the OpenCV file path like `cv2.VideoCapture(best.url)` so design your code to be flexible to adjust for a URL change (so processing still carries on as usual, no sudden stops).

Comment: @VC.One I am very glad for your advice. Let's write a program to read it again every hour and run it.I will get back to you when I have the results.

Comment: @VC.One It is now 9 hours old and working fine. Thanks to you, I appreciate it very much.