# Download YouTube live stream in real time with Python

Tags: python, opencv, youtube, video-streaming, real-time

Is there a way to download a YouTube live stream as it's happening in real-time in Python?

My best guess would be to use Pafy. For example,

```
import pafy

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_9OBhtLA9Ig"
video = pafy.new(url)
best = video.getbest(preftype="mp4")
```

However, I'm not sure if this works for live streams and how to download frames in real-time.

Or maybe using `vidgear`:

```
from vidgear.gears import CamGear

stream = CamGear(source='https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ', stream_mode = True, logging=True).start()

while True:    
    frame = stream.read()
```

I'm also not sure if that works in real-time.

These code examples are borrowed from a related question: [How to read Youtube live stream using openCV python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43032163/how-to-read-youtube-live-stream-using-opencv-python)

I'd like to be able to process the frames in a while loop kind of like this:

```
while True:
    # The current frame in real-time
    frame = get_frame()
```

Comment: why does the previous question not solve your problem? if it does, why do you ask? -- why do you speak of "downloading" when clearly you don't intend to save the file but decode it right away?

Comment: Good points. I may have gotten the terminology wrong. I’m not familiar with either of these solutions, so I don’t know how compatible they are for real-time livestreams.