# Python - Web Scraping - Requests - OS Error ETIMEDOUT

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a website, but am receiving the following error:

```
('Connection aborted.', OSError("(60, 'ETIMEDOUT')",))
```

I tried to change the timeout = None within response.get(), but I still received the error.

How should I handle the above error given the below code?  For some reason, this error only appears when I try and scrape that url, all others have worked fine for me.

The below code was suggested based off of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511337/correct-way-to-try-except-using-python-requests-module).

```
# Import packages
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

#Input URL
url = "https://www...."

# Try requests.get()
try:    
    r = requests.get(url)
except requests.ConnectionError as e:
    print("OOPS!! Connection Error. Make sure you are connected to Internet. Technical Details given below.\n")
    print(str(e))
except requests.Timeout as e:
    print("OOPS!! Timeout Error")
    print(str(e))
except requests.RequestException as e:
    print("OOPS!! General Error")
    print(str(e))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Someone closed the program")
```

I also tried a retry mechanism, but to no luck, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083987/how-to-retry-after-exception):

```
for i in range(0,10):
    while True:
        try:
            r = requests.get(url)
        except requests.ConnectionError as e:
            print("OOPS!! Connection Error. Make sure you are connected to Internet. Technical Details given below.\n")
            print(str(e))
            continue
        break
```

Comment: If normal browsing works ok, I would suggest looking at network inspector and see, what headers are sent. Maybe you need to set them in `requests` too.

Comment: What's the website URL?

Comment: Normal browsing works, it was the headers not being set. Thanks! How exactly do headers work? @AndrejKesely

Comment: @steich Headers are part of HTTP protocol (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields), they are sent with each request and response. With `requests`, you just supply them in the form of `requests.get(url, headers={...})`