# retry a function with backoff with different argument and timeout

Tags: python, decorator

I am trying to implement a retry ability whenever a function fails with an index error. I started with this:

I know the reason for failure is passing high value to curr_val, but setting high values will generate better output

```
#these lines are inside another for loop
curr_val=40
while True:
    try:
        ret1, ret2 = extract(arg1,arg2,val=curr_val)
    except IndexError:
        curr_val -=5
        continue
    break  
##process ret1
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25912659/1076264) answer, it is possible to use the decorator (like tenacity) to handle such cases, supporting any kind of exception.

my current try with tenacity is as follows:

```
curr_val = 5
@tenacity.retry(wait=tenacity.wait_fixed(1))
def try_to_extract():
    try:
        return extract(arg1,arg2,val=curr_val)
    except Exception:
        curr_val -=1
        raise
```

However, it does not have access to the outside variables and keeps raising exception, without changing curr_val

Can anyone let me know how to handle this? meaning using `curr_val` inside retry and handle this case. (retrying with another argument(decremented curr_val), in case of failure or timeout)

Comment: try tenacity(https://github.com/jd/tenacity). it may have all functionalities you need.

Comment: If your question is how to use a library function, then you need to defer to the official documentation for said library.

Comment: "Can anyone let me know how to do this? meaning using one of these maintaining libraries to implement handle this case." You are asking how to use a library. If you have a *specific* question about implementation, then update your post with your code attempt and what exactly the problem is with your attempt. Right now, your question is vaguely "how do I use one of these libraries to implement this feature", which is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: The link in *your* post to the `backoff` library has plenty of examples and clear documentation for how to implement various backoff/retry processes. If you have a specific problem with one of the approaches using the library *you have requested* then you need to post it. You claim your question is "not a straightforward documentation question or library 'how to use'" but you have not indicated otherwise yet through any edits or clarifying comments -- you are just complaining about downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

the iterator can help this.

```py
@tenacity.retry
def try_to_extract(value_iter):
    curr_val = next(value_iter)
    print(curr_val)
    try:
        return extract(arg1,arg2,val=curr_val)
    except Exception:
        raise

curr_val = 40
try_to_extract(itertools.count(curr_val, -1))
```