# How to retry urllib2.request when fails?

Tags: python, decorator, urllib2, urllib3

When `urllib2.request` reaches timeout, a `urllib2.URLError` exception is raised.
What is the pythonic way to retry establishing a connection?

Comment: This question should answer yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712524/handling-urllib2s-timeout-python

Comment: I didn't ask how to catch the expection. I wanted to know if there is a pythonic way to retry establish the connection.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed the problem was in detecting the timeout had been reached, not in re-establising the connection. Could you not call urlopen() in the exception block?

Comment: That is possible, but doesn't seem very pythonic. If I'd like to retry three times, I'll have to nest the try-except blocks, and it looks ugly.

Comment: This might be of some help then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567622/is-there-a-pythonic-way-to-try-something-up-to-a-maximum-number-of-times

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I would use a [retry](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/11/trying-out-retry-decorator-python/) decorator. There are other ones out there, but this one works pretty well. Here's how you can use it:

```
@retry(urllib2.URLError, tries=4, delay=3, backoff=2)
def urlopen_with_retry():
    return urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com")
```

This will retry the function if `URLError` is raised. Check the link above for documentation on the parameters, but basically it will retry a maximum of 4 times, with an exponential backoff delay doubling each time, e.g. 3 seconds, 6 seconds, 12 seconds.

Comment: This is a really cool snippet. Do you know an alternative, but as a context manager ?

Comment: Hmm, I think you could probably rewrite it as a context manager pretty easily, but I don't have one offhand.

Comment: It's no easy to do, since there is not easy way to capture the block inside the with statement. You need some deep introspection.

Comment: No, I don't think that's true. Exceptions are re-raised inside a context manager after the yield.

Comment: The problem is not the exception, but the code raising the exception. How do you retry a code if you can't run it ? There is no notion of anonymous bloc in Python. It's doable, but not intuitive.

Comment: Ah, I see. It would be even harder if the calling code was not a with block. I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 9):

There are a few libraries out there that specialize in this.

One is [backoff](https://github.com/litl/backoff), which is designed with a particularly functional sensibility. Decorators are passed arbitrary callables returning generators which yield successive delay values. A simple exponential backoff with a maximum retry time of 32 seconds could be defined as:

```
@backoff.on_exception(backoff.expo,
                      urllib2.URLError,
                      max_value=32)
def url_open(url):
    return urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com")
```

Another is [retrying](https://github.com/rholder/retrying) which has very similar functionality but an API where retry parameters are specified by way of predefined keyword args.

Answer (score 6):

For Python3, you can use [`urllib3.Retry`](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/urllib3.util.html#urllib3.util.Retry):

```
from urllib3 import Retry, PoolManager


retries = Retry(connect=5, read=2, redirect=5, backoff_factor=0.1)
http = PoolManager(retries=retries)
response = http.request('GET', 'http://example.com/')
```

> If the backoff_factor is 0.1, then :func:`.sleep` will sleep
> for [0.0s, 0.2s, 0.4s, ...] between retries. It will never be longer
> than :attr:`Retry.BACKOFF_MAX`.
> urllib3 will sleep for::
>
> ```
>         {backoff factor} * (2 ** ({number of total retries} - 1))
> ```

Answer (score 5):

To retry on timeout you could catch the exception as [@Karl Barker suggested in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9446387/4279):

```
assert ntries >= 1
for i in range(1, ntries+1):
    try:
        page = urlopen(request, timeout=timeout)
        break # success
    except URLError as err:
        if i == ntries or not isinstance(err.reason, socket.timeout):
           raise # propagate last timeout or non-timeout errors
# use page here
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `err` is not defined in the `else:` block, so if your code reaches the else block you'll get `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'err' referenced before assignment`

Comment: @elboulangero: I've updated the answer to raise inside the except clause.