# How to keep trying urllib2 request via proxy when we get any type of error(or timeout)?

Tags: python, urllib2

I am making a html request using urllib2 method(inside a for loop) but sometimes i get errors or timeouts so i have to start all over the for loop. Could any one show me how i can modify my code so it keeps trying until we don't get error instead of restring the for loop all over again ?

```
    import urllib2,re

    proxy = "*.*.*.*:8080"
    proxies = {"http":"http://%s" % proxy}
    headers={'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}

    //rest of code here

    for num,cname in enumerate(match):
        r = re.compile('epi/(.*?)/')
        m = r.search(cname[0])
        episodeId = m.group(1)

        url = "http://api.somesite.net/api/data/Episode/"+str(episodeId);

        proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler(proxies)
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support, urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=0))
        urllib2.install_opener(opener)
        req = urllib2.Request(url, None, headers)
   try:
      html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
   except urllib2.URLError, e:
      raise MyException("There was an error: %r" % e)

  @retry(urllib2.URLError, tries=4, delay=3, backoff=2)

def urlopen_with_retry():
        return urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com")
```

Comment: See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712524/handling-urllib2s-timeout-python)

Comment: Thanks for reply . My question is not only about error detection but also how to retry the request again inside the loop instead of starting all over again!Is there a way to try the request again and again ?

Comment: you can use `retry` decorator or a loop with try/except block, see first two answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446387/how-to-retry-urllib2-request-when-fails)

Comment: I edited my post . could tell me if it is correct ?how to pass the current url to urlopen_with_retry function ?

Comment: okay, I think it's better to use simplier solution, than the decorator I suggested first. I've posted the answer. The code is not tested, but should work fine.

Answer (score -1):

As we discussed in comments, you can use `try/except` to avoid crashing while looping over (I see that you have changed you original code after this suggestion)

Then you can specify longer timeout in seconds, when using `urlopen` (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen)).

Additionally, inside your `for` loop, you can add another loop that will try to retrieve the data certain number of times or break as soon as `urlopen` gets what you need. Code below is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9446851/4241180):

```
# number of attempt urlopen tries to open your url
attempts = 10

for _ in range(attempts):
    try:
        # you can use timeout argument for urlopen
        html = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=timeout).read()
        # urlopen successfully get the data
        break
    # urlopen fails to retrieve data
    except urllib2.URLError as err:
        print("Oops! urlopen failed")
# all attempts failed
else:
    print("Oops! All attempts failed")
# now use your html variable here
# ...
```

P.S. For those who downvoted: OP has changed his question/code after discussion in comments. This answer is a follow-up of that discussion, so please take the context into account.