# Why does python use 'else' after for and while loops?

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, for-else

I understand how this construct works:

```py
for i in range(10):
    print(i)

    if i == 9:
        print("Too big - I'm giving up!")
        break
else:
    print("Completed successfully")
```

But I don't understand why `else` is used as the keyword here, since it suggests the code in question only runs if the `for` block does not complete, which is the opposite of what it does! No matter how I think about it, my brain can't progress seamlessly from the `for` statement to the `else` block. To me, `continue` or `continuewith` would make more sense (and I'm trying to train myself to read it as such).

I'm wondering how Python coders read this construct in their head (or aloud, if you like). Perhaps I'm missing something that would make such code blocks more easily decipherable?

---

<sub>This question is about the *underlying design decision*, i.e. *why it is useful* to be able to write this code. See also [Else clause on Python while statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295938) for the specific question about *what the syntax means*.</sub>

Comment: You might like to translate it to "then" in your head.

Comment: Don't forget the key line in the Zen of Python: "... that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch."

Comment: In my head I translate it into *"if not break"*. And, since `break` is used a lot in *"I've found it"* loops, you can translate it to *"if not found"*, which is not far from what `else` reads

Comment: @MestreLion: Well, but you should also add *"... or if continue"*, and then it is really strange.

Comment: @pepr Then the `continue` in the last loop run has to be hit before the `break`. So the `break` was not reached.

Comment: This for...else construct is useful at least for the cases where you want to implement get_or_create() type of operations, i.e. looping through a data structure and get the first match if none was found then create a new entry in the data structure.

Comment: I think the real question many people have here is "What's the difference between `for ... else foo()` and just putting `foo()` after the for loop?" And the answer is that they behave differently **only** if the loop contains a `break` (as described in detail below).

Comment: What I wasn't sure about :`>>> for i in []:
...     pass
... else:
...     print 'else will run on empty list'
...     
else will run on empty list
` - save next one's 5 minutes

Comment: It's almost like `else if not break` or (equivalently) `else if not (condition raising break)`

Comment: This is an excellent explanation: http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/break_else.html

Comment: To add another thought: usage of `else` in a `for...else` is consistent with the [optional else clause](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#try) in a `try...except`.  Whether or not it's intuitive, at least it's consistent.

Comment: Related post - [Else clause on Python while statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3295938/465053)

Comment: Almost 10 years after this question has been asked and after programming with Python for 3 years, this is the first time I've seen the "for-else", "while-else" construct.  I hope its low frequency use declines further into evaporation.  The world is full of junior programmers that will "un-indent" the "else" to "fix" the bug they found.

Comment: @MestreLion Please add your comment about *"if not break"* as an answer. To me your comment was 1000x better than all answers.

Comment: its more like 
```
elif not for:
 #do something after looping

#and then some...

```

Comment: It becomes much more intuitive if you view it not as `for`…`else`, but `break`…`else`.

Comment: The `else:` makes more sense if you mentally translate `break` as `found!`

Answer (score 403, accepted):

It's a strange construct even to seasoned Python coders. When used in conjunction with for-loops it basically means "find some item in the iterable, else if none was found do ...". As in:

```
found_obj = None
for obj in objects:
    if obj.key == search_key:
        found_obj = obj
        break
else:
    print('No object found.')
```

But anytime you see this construct, a better alternative is to either encapsulate the search in a function:

```
def find_obj(search_key):
    for obj in objects:
        if obj.key == search_key:
            return obj
```

Or use a list comprehension:

```
matching_objs = [o for o in objects if o.key == search_key]
if matching_objs:
    print('Found {}'.format(matching_objs[0]))
else:
    print('No object found.')
```

It is not semantically equivalent to the other two versions, but works good enough in non-performance critical code where it doesn't matter whether you iterate the whole list or not. Others may disagree, but I personally would avoid ever using the for-else or while-else blocks in production code.

See also [[Python-ideas] Summary of for...else threads](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2009-October/006155.html)

Comment: The list comprehension is the wrong one-liner. If you're looking for a single item, as in the `for` loop examples, and want to use a generator expression / list comprehension, then you want `next((o for o in objects if o.key == search_key), None)` or wrap it in a `try` / `except` and use no default value instead of an `if` / `else`.

Comment: and like Lance Helsten's answer, there are actual cases where it's better to use a `for/else` construct.

Comment: Cheers. I had a badly indented file where an `else` got paired with a `for` and I had no idea that was legal.

Comment: The for...else construct is useful at least for the cases where you want to implement get_or_create() type of operations, i.e. looping through a data structure and get the first match if none was found then create a new entry in the data structure.

Comment: I think that the for loop is the most obvious of the constructs there.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the else clause will run even if the for loop has values unless a `break` statement is explicity run as in this example. From the docs above: "The `else` clause has another perceived problem: if there is no `break` in the
loop, the `else` clause is functionally redundant.". e.g. `for x in [1, 2, 3]:\n print x\n else:\n print 'this executes due to no break'`

Comment: In the list-comprehension, there is no break !

Comment: it's strange if you don't think of the case but i don't find it to be that strange. the case for not having something to loop through is common. semantically for beginners or non-programmers, though, it's probably strange.

Comment: For the function version, should there be `print('No object found.')` as the last line of the function?

Comment: I'm happy that I didn't read *"find some item in the iterable, else if none was found do ..."* before actually knowing how for-else works because this would horribly mislead me how for-else works. `else` executes when loop ends naturally (i.e. w/o `break`) and the *"find"* part is false for regular for-else loop w/o `if` and `break` statements which you added in your code.

Comment: ""find some item in the iterable, else if none was found do ..." this is wrong. We iterate for lots of reasons other than "finding things".

Comment: Am I right in thinking that the else block of a for-loop only executes if the for-loop completes running THROUGH THE WHOLE TARGET ITERABLE? I assume this syntax is extremely suited for the case of a for loop that terminates or breaks once a target is found. Assuming the loop is coded to break when a target is found, it is logical that when the loop completes without being interrupted, no item was found and the search condition is False.

Comment: I agree with several previous comments that this answer is misleading and/or partially incorrect. The answer by @lance-helsten is spot on and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @aaa90210 No, it is not wrong. The for-else idiom always implements a search with a fallback in case the search fails. For loops are indeed used for lots of reasons, but that is not what this question or answer is about.

Comment: If it's only necessary to determine *whether* there is a match, rather than actually reporting the match, using `any` is simpler than the search function. In 3.8 and above, `any` can also report the first match using the walrus operator (`:=`).

Answer (score 887):

A common construct is to run a loop until something is found and then to break out of the loop. The problem is that if I break out of the loop or the loop ends I need to determine which case happened. One method is to create a flag or store variable that will let me do a second test to see how the loop was exited.

For example assume that I need to search through a list and process each item until a flag item is found and then stop processing. If the flag item is missing then an exception needs to be raised.

Using the Python `for`...`else` construct you have

```
for i in mylist:
    if i == theflag:
        break
    process(i)
else:
    raise ValueError("List argument missing terminal flag.")
```

Compare this to a method that does not use this syntactic sugar:

```
flagfound = False
for i in mylist:
    if i == theflag:
        flagfound = True
        break
    process(i)

if not flagfound:
    raise ValueError("List argument missing terminal flag.")
```

In the first case the `raise` is bound tightly to the for loop it works with. In the second the binding is not as strong and errors may be introduced during maintenance.

Comment: I'd have to say this syntactic sugar might rot your project's teeth.  This would not make a ```Python: the good parts``` book.

Comment: Can you confirm that in your example, `process(i)` happens for every item in `mylist` strictly before `theflag`, and not to `theflag` itself? Is it what was intended?

Comment: ``process`` will execute on each ``i`` that exists in the list before ``theflag`` is reached, it will not be executed on elements in the list after ``theflag``, and it will not be executed on ``theflag``.

Comment: I think it is useful in case of inner loops. For example, inner loop wants to break the outer loop on break statement.

Comment: I like this response. The only suggestion I would make is the logic afterwards to more closely resemble the 'else' in the loop. For example:
>>if flagfound:
>>    # do nothing; the flag was found
>>    pass
>>else:
>>    # same code as the for-else
>>    raise ValueError("List argument missing terminal flag.")

Comment: the else statement also gets executed if the iterable has no elements

Comment: I think they made a mistake by calling it `else:`. It's really misleading. Before trying it, I was pretty sure it runs when there are no elements to iterate. More accurate name would have been `passed:`, `completed:` or something.

Comment: As for maintenance, put the "for-else" into an "if" block and see if your maintainers don't more than once out-dent the "else" to bind to the "if" thinking they are fixing a bug.

Comment: Also, without for/else, you get lint warnings ("might be referenced before assignment") for variables defined inside the loop and used after the loop. Unless you define them before the loop, too.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. It looks like you didn't read the question, only the title.

Comment: I haven't really seen this used much with extra process(i), only with pure "found or not found" searches.  The coupling of "process until this point" condition with "want to know if you stopped" feels somewhat coincidental; if I need both I'd consider a boolean flag which leaves flexibility e.g. keep processing anyway. Or better yet first pure loop to find the index / handle not found case; then separate loop processing slices of the list e.g. `mylist[:index]`.

Answer (score 268):

There's an excellent presentation by Raymond Hettinger, titled [*Transforming Code into Beautiful, Idiomatic Python*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSGv2VnC0go), in which he briefly addresses the history of the `for ... else` construct. The relevant section is "Distinguishing multiple exit points in loops" [starting at 15:50](https://youtu.be/OSGv2VnC0go?t=950) and continuing for about three minutes. Here are the high points:

- The `for ... else` construct was devised by Donald Knuth as a replacement for certain `GOTO` use cases;
- Reusing the `else` keyword made sense because "it's what Knuth used, and people knew, at that time, all [`for` statements] had embedded an `if` and `GOTO` underneath, and they expected the `else`;"
- In hindsight, it should have been called "no break" (or possibly "nobreak"), and then it wouldn't be confusing.*

So, if the question is, "Why don't they change this keyword?" then [Cat Plus Plus probably gave the most accurate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9979985/2359271) – at this point, it would be too destructive to existing code to be practical. But if the question you're really asking is why `else` was reused in the first place, well, apparently it seemed like a good idea at the time.

Personally, I like the compromise of commenting `# no break` in-line wherever the `else` could be mistaken, at a glance, as belonging inside the loop. It's reasonably clear and concise. This option gets a brief mention in [the summary that Bjorn linked](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2009-October/006155.html) at the end of his answer:

> For completeness, I should mention that with a slight change in
>   syntax, programmers who want this syntax can have it right now:
>
> ```
> for item in sequence:
>     process(item)
> else:  # no break
>     suite
> ```

---

<sub>* Bonus quote from that part of the video: "Just like if we called lambda *makefunction,* nobody would ask, 'What does lambda do?'"</sub>

Comment: Why not add support for nobreak next to else, have both be equal and exist alongside eachother and make a clear PEP style rule that nobreak should be used instead of else?

Comment: @jaaq I can't speak for Python core devs but consider the PEP 20 line "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."

Comment: yeah that's true, but they did the same thing with the division operator, where one could import division from `__future__` to replace / with standard division and add the // floor division operator.

Comment: [recent pep doc](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/#id3) states that multiple ways is OK, just not multiple *obvious* ways. Since a `nobreak` keyword could be *more* obvious, maybe this is indeed a way to improve the syntax.

Comment: "nobreak" would be a new keyword, and, as a rule, language designers are very hesitant to add keywords to an existing language, because it insta-breaks all code that has used that identifier for something else.

Comment: Though the example is incomplete because `for ... else` never makes sense without `break`.

Comment: The `# no break` comment seems like a really nice idea to me. Only seeing `else` can be very misleading, as in 99% of cases `else` is related to an `if`, so adding a comment like that can be useful. That's what comments should be used for, after all - commenting non-obvious or potentially misleading stuff.

Comment: @zwol The new PEG grammar makes it easier to introduce new "context-sensitive" keywords (Python `match` remains a valid identifier in 3.10 even though it also introduces the new pattern-matching statement.) However, I do think the bar should still remain high for adding new keywords.

Comment: Thanks for the actual answer to the question.  My take is that it's a symptom of the PHP-disease.  Like PHP just included stuff from everywhere, and left the source naming conventions intact; camelCase, PascalCase, snake_case, whatever the source of some functions used, PHP used.  Now I realize that Python, or rather Guido, wasn't immune to this.  "We do for... else because Knuth did it".  Same for continue.  Both bad non-choices.  And don't get me started on the return value of os.stat and the stat module.

Comment: @zwol Which means it was exactly the thing Python 3000 was meant to do (and did, in many cases).

Answer (score 70):

To make it simple, you can think of it like that;

- If it encounters the `break` command in the `for` loop, the `else` part will not be called.
- If it does not encounter the `break` command in the `for` loop, the `else` part will be called.

In other words, if for loop iteration is not "broken" with `break`, the `else` part will be called.

Comment: The `else` block will also not be executed if the body of the loop raises an exception.

Comment: And the else block will also be executed if the list is empty and the for loop does not iterate at all.

Comment: If like to read `for/else` as `for/nobreak`.

Comment: @Amal K the else still executes if the exception is handled with a try-except

Answer (score 47):

Because they didn't want to introduce a new keyword to the language. Each one steals an identifier and causes backwards compatibility problems, so it's usually a last resort.

Comment: Seems like `finally` would have been a better choice in that case. Was the finally keyword not yet present at the time this construct was introduced?

Comment: @Wallacoloo `finally` isn't much better, because it implies the block would always be executed after the loop, and it isn't (because that'd be redundant with just putting the code to run after the loop).

Comment: It also cannot be `finally` because the else clause is executed also when `continue` is used in the for loop -- that is possibly many times and not only at the end.

Comment: @pepr `else` clause execution is not affected by `continue` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) and [test code](http://ideone.com/Tq400j))

Comment: @AirThomas: +1. You are right. The `else` is executed only when the `continue` was the one for the last iteration.

Comment: `completed` would have been a better keyword here; to signify the that the for-loop's execution was not broken (irrespective of whether any loops were actually performed).  At least then if someone accidentally shifts the indentation it wouldn't end up causing incorrect behaviour because the `else` has suddenly moved to an `if` construct....

Comment: `else` would have been more fitting if the loop did not run at all (no matching elements)

Comment: the best keyword would be something like `afterBreak`, but ofcourse a keyword should be one singular word, so not really sure what the keyword should be.

Comment: @Anm replacing `else` with `afterBreak` doesn't make sense. `else` doesn't execute after a break. `else` executes if the loop finishes without the use of a break or uncaught exception.

Answer (score 26):

The easiest way I found to 'get' what the for/else did, and more importantly, when to use it, was to concentrate on where the break statement jumps to. The For/else construct is a single block. The break jumps out of the block, and so jumps 'over' the else clause. If the contents of the else clause simply followed the for clause, it would never be jumped over, and so the equivalent logic would have to be provided by putting it in an if. This has been said before, but not quite in these words, so it may help somebody else. Try running the following code fragment. I'm wholeheartedly in favour of the 'no break' comment for clarity.

```
for a in range(3):
    print(a)
    if a==4: # change value to force break or not
        break
else: #no break  +10 for whoever thought of this decoration
    print('for completed OK')

print('statement after for loop')
```

EDIT - I notice this question is still running

Second better thoughts ...

The 'no break' comment is a negative. It's so much easier to understand a positive assertion, and that is that the `for` iterable was exhausted.

```
for a in range(3):
    print(a)
    if a==4: # change value to force break or not
        print('ending for loop with a break')
        break
else: # when iterable exhausted  
    print('ending for loop as iterable exhausted')

print('for loop ended one way or another')
```

That also reinforces this interpretation

```
if iterable_supplies_a_value:
    run_the_for_with_that_value
else:
    do_something_else
```

Comment: *"The break jumps out of the block, and so jumps 'over' the else clause"* - while this may be helpful as  a way of "getting" `for:`/`else:`, it doesn't really provide a justification for the keyword being `else`. Given the framing given here, `then:` seems like it would be much more natural. (There *are* reasons for `else` being chosen, given in other answers - they're just not provided here.)

Comment: @Neil_UK "if iterable_supplies_a_value:" sounds like "else:" runs only when the iterable was empty, which is a common wrong guess of what it does.  But previous parts of your answer explain it correctly.  As written, it's unclear what you meant by "That also reinforces this interpretation"

Answer (score 24):

I think documentation has a great explanation of  *else*, *continue*

> [...] it is executed when the loop terminates through exhaustion of the list (with for) or when the condition becomes false (with while), but not when the loop is terminated by a break statement."

Source: [Python 2 docs: Tutorial on control flow](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Answer (score 18):

Since the technical part has been pretty much answered, my comment is just in relation with the **confusion** that produce this *recycled* keyword.

Being Python a very *eloquent* programming language, the misuse of a keyword is more notorious. The `else` keyword perfectly describes  part of the flow of a decision tree, "if you can't do this, (else) do that". It's *implied* in our own language.

Instead, using this keyword with `while` and `for` statements creates confusion. The reason, our career as programmers has taught us that the `else` statement resides within a decision tree; its **logical scope**, a wrapper that *conditionally* return a path to follow. Meanwhile, loop statements have a figurative explicit goal to reach something. The goal is met after continuous iterations of a process.

`if / else` *indicate a path to follow*. Loops *follow a path until the "goal" is completed*.

The issue is that `else` is a word that clearly define the last option in a condition. The **semantics** of the word are both *shared* by Python and Human Language. But the else word in Human Language is never used to indicate the actions someone or something will take after something is completed. It will be used if, in the process of completing it, an issue rises (more like a *break* statement).

At the end, the keyword will remain in Python. It's clear it was mistake, clearer when every programmer tries to come up with a story to understand its usage like some mnemonic device. I'd have loved if they have chosen instead the keyword `then`. I believe that this keyword fits perfectly in that iterative flow, the *payoff* after the loop.

It resembles that situation that some child has after following every step in assembling a toy: And **THEN** what Dad?

Comment: I think that this answer addresses the issue of confusion I think the OP was talking about. The else keyword does exactly the opposite of what you would expect of from the English meaning of else when attached to the action of for. In theory, the for ... else could have worked differently in that you end up in the else part when the loop is broken out of, But the problem is that to use it to find element x, and handle the case where x is not found, you may have to use a flag or another test after the whole for .. else construct

Comment: My career as a programmer has taught me nothing of the sort.  Even if I had had a career as a programmer, this would still be true.

Answer (score 15):

Great answers are:

- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23748240/5492820) which explain the history, and
- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23626222/5492820) gives the right
  citation to ease yours translation/understanding.

My note here comes from what Donald Knuth once said (sorry can't find reference) that there is a construct where while-else is indistinguishable from if-else, namely (in Python):

```py
x = 2
while x > 3:
    print("foo")
    break
else:
    print("boo")
```

has the same flow (excluding low level differences) as:

```py
x = 2
if x > 3:
    print("foo")
else:
    print("boo")
```

The point is that if-else can be considered as syntactic sugar for while-else which has implicit `break` at the end of its `if` block. The opposite implication, that `while` loop is extension to `if`, is more common (it's just repeated/looped conditional check), because `if` is often taught before `while`. However that isn't true because that would mean `else` block in while-else would be executed **each time** when condition is false.

To ease your understanding think of it that way:

> Without `break`, `return`, etc., loop ends only when condition is no longer true and in such case `else` block will also execute once. In case of Python `for` you must consider C-style `for` loops (with conditions) or translate them to `while`.

Another note:

> Premature `break`, `return`, etc. inside loop makes impossible for condition to become false because execution jumped out of the loop while condition was true and it would never come back to check it again.

Answer (score 14):

I read it something like:

If still on the conditions to run the loop, do stuff, *else* do something else.

Comment: Your *still on the conditions* is helpful (+1) although it is wrong - it's human ;-)

Comment: -1; this pronunciation of `for:`/`else:` makes it sound like the `else:` will always run after the loop, which isn't the case.

Answer (score 10):

> I'm wondering how Python coders read this construct in their head (or aloud, if you like).

I simply think in my head:

> **"else no `break` was encountered..."**

That's it!

This is because the `else` clause executes only if a `break` statement was NOT encountered in the `for` loop.

Reference:

See here: https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html#else-clause (emphasis added, and "not" changed to "NOT"):

> `for` loops also have an `else` clause which most of us are unfamiliar with. **The `else` clause executes after the loop completes normally. This means that the loop did NOT encounter a break statement.**

---

That being said, I recommend *against* using this unusual feature of the language. Don't use the `else` clause after a for loop. It's confusing to most people, and just slows down their ability to read and understand the code.

Comment: I could not convince myself that *normal* completion of a loop is through a `break` statement. For me it is otherwise. hence not using this weird overthought construct.

Answer (score 7):

I read it like "When the `iterable` is exhausted completely, and the execution is about to proceed to the next statement after finishing the `for`, the else clause will be executed." Thus, when the iteration is broken by `break`, this will not be executed.

Answer (score 6):

**I agree, it's more like an 'elif not [condition(s) raising break]'.**

I know this is an old thread, but I am looking into the same question right now,  and I'm not sure anyone has captured the answer to this question in the way I understand it.

For me, there are three ways of "reading" the `else` in `For... else` or `While... else` statements, all of which are equivalent, are:

1. `else` `==` `if the loop completes normally (without a break or error)`
2. `else` `==` `if the loop does not encounter a break`
3. `else` `==` `else not (condition raising break)` (presumably there is such a condition, or you wouldn't have a loop)

**So, essentially, the "else" in a loop is really an "elif ..." where '...' is (1) no break, which is equivalent to (2) NOT [condition(s) raising break].**

I think the key is that the `else` is pointless without the 'break', so a `for...else` includes:

```
for:
    do stuff
    conditional break # implied by else
else not break:
    do more stuff
```

So, essential elements of a `for...else` loop are as follows, and you would read them in plainer English as:

```
for:
    do stuff
    condition:
        break
else: # read as "else not break" or "else not condition"
    do more stuff
```

As the other posters have said, a break is generally raised when you are able to locate what your loop is looking for, so the `else:` becomes "what to do if target item not located".

**Example**

You can also use exception handling, breaks, and for loops all together.

```
for x in range(0,3):
    print("x: {}".format(x))
    if x == 2:
        try:
            raise AssertionError("ASSERTION ERROR: x is {}".format(x))
        except:
            print(AssertionError("ASSERTION ERROR: x is {}".format(x)))
            break
else:
    print("X loop complete without error")
```

*Result*

```
x: 0
x: 1
x: 2
ASSERTION ERROR: x is 2
----------
# loop not completed (hit break), so else didn't run
```

**Example**

Simple example with a break being hit.

```
for y in range(0,3):
    print("y: {}".format(y))
    if y == 2: # will be executed
        print("BREAK: y is {}\n----------".format(y))
        break
else: # not executed because break is hit
    print("y_loop completed without break----------\n")
```

*Result*

```
y: 0
y: 1
y: 2
BREAK: y is 2
----------
# loop not completed (hit break), so else didn't run
```

**Example**

Simple example where there no break, no condition raising a break, and no error are encountered.

```
for z in range(0,3):
     print("z: {}".format(z))
     if z == 4: # will not be executed
         print("BREAK: z is {}\n".format(y))
         break
     if z == 4: # will not be executed
         raise AssertionError("ASSERTION ERROR: x is {}".format(x))
else:
     print("z_loop complete without break or error\n----------\n")
```

*Result*

```
z: 0
z: 1
z: 2
z_loop complete without break or error
----------
```

Answer (score 6):

The `else` keyword can be confusing here, and as many people have pointed out, something like `nobreak`, `notbreak` is more appropriate.

In order to understand `for ... else ...` logically, compare it with `try...except...else`, not `if...else...`, most of python programmers are familiar with the following code:

```
try:
    do_something()
except:
    print("Error happened.") # The try block threw an exception
else:
    print("Everything is find.") # The try block does things just find.
```

Similarly, think of `break` as a special kind of `Exception`:

```
for x in iterable:
    do_something(x)
except break:
    pass # Implied by Python's loop semantics
else:
    print('no break encountered')  # No break statement was encountered
```

The difference is `python` implies `except break` and you can not write it out, so it becomes:

```
for x in iterable:
    do_something(x)
else:
    print('no break encountered')  # No break statement was encountered
```

Yes, I know this comparison can be difficult and tiresome, but it does clarify the confusion.

Comment: You should make a link to resource when you copy from it: [Nick Coghlan's Python Notes](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/break_else.html).

Comment: @godaygo thanks for the link. I read and accept the concept when first learning python, didn't memorize the source when writing the answer.

Comment: @cizixs You *"didn't memorise the source"* but just happened to include entire sentences of comments identical to the original? Ooookaaaay.

Comment: I came here looking for this one, but..  isn't `try: stuff(); except: error(); else: ok()` really the same as `try: stuff(); ok(); except: error()` ?

Comment: @phil Not exactly, because if there's an exception raised inside `else`, it'll bubble up.

Answer (score 5):

Codes in `else` statement block will be executed when the `for` loop was not be broke.

```
for x in xrange(1,5):
    if x == 5:
        print 'find 5'
        break
else:
    print 'can not find 5!'
#can not find 5!
```

From the [docs:  break and continue Statements, and else Clauses on Loops](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

> Loop statements may have an else clause; it is executed when the loop terminates through exhaustion of the list (with for) or when the condition becomes false (with while), but not when the loop is terminated by a break statement. This is exemplified by the following loop, which searches for prime numbers:
>
> ```
> >>> for n in range(2, 10):
> ...     for x in range(2, n):
> ...         if n % x == 0:
> ...             print(n, 'equals', x, '*', n//x)
> ...             break
> ...     else:
> ...         # loop fell through without finding a factor
> ...         print(n, 'is a prime number')
> ...
> 2 is a prime number
> 3 is a prime number
> 4 equals 2 * 2
> 5 is a prime number
> 6 equals 2 * 3
> 7 is a prime number
> 8 equals 2 * 4
> 9 equals 3 * 3
> ```
>
> (Yes, this is the correct code. Look closely: the else clause belongs to the for loop, not the if statement.)
>
> When used with a loop, the else clause has more in common with the else clause of a try statement than it does that of if statements: a try statement’s else clause runs when no exception occurs, and a loop’s else clause runs when no break occurs. For more on the try statement and exceptions, see Handling Exceptions.
>
> The continue statement, also borrowed from C, continues with the next iteration of the loop:
>
> ```
> >>> for num in range(2, 10):
> ...     if num % 2 == 0:
> ...         print("Found an even number", num)
> ...         continue
> ...     print("Found a number", num)
> Found an even number 2
> Found a number 3
> Found an even number 4
> Found a number 5
> Found an even number 6
> Found a number 7
> Found an even number 8
> Found a number 9
> ```

Comment: This adds nothing and doesn't answer the question, which is not *how* but *why*.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way to think about it that I haven't seen anyone else mention above:

First, remember that for-loops are basically just syntactic sugar around while-loops. For example, the loop

```
for item in sequence:
    do_something(item)
```

can be rewritten (approximately) as

```
item = None
while sequence.hasnext():
    item = sequence.next()
    do_something(item)
```

Second, remember that while-loops are basically just repeated if-blocks! You can always read a while-loop as "if this condition is true, execute the body, then come back and check again".

So while/else makes perfect sense: It's the exact same structure as if/else, with the added functionality of looping until the condition becomes false instead of just checking the condition once.

And then for/else makes perfect sense too: because all for-loops are just syntactic sugar on top of while-loops, you just need to figure out what the underlying while-loop's implicit conditional is, and then the else corresponds to when that condition becomes False.

Answer (score 3):

```
for i in range(3):
    print(i)

    if i == 2:
        print("Too big - I'm giving up!")
        break;
else:
    print("Completed successfully")
```

"else" here is crazily simple, just mean

1, "if `for clause` is completed"

```
for i in range(3):
    print(i)

    if i == 2:
        print("Too big - I'm giving up!")
        break;
if "for clause is completed":
    print("Completed successfully")
```

It's wielding to write such long statements as "for clause is completed", so they introduce "else".

`else` here is a if in its nature.

2, However, How about `for clause is not run at all`

```
In [331]: for i in range(0):
     ...:     print(i)
     ...: 
     ...:     if i == 9:
     ...:         print("Too big - I'm giving up!")
     ...:         break
     ...: else:
     ...:     print("Completed successfully")
     ...:     
Completed successfully
```

So it's completely statement is logic combination:

```
if "for clause is completed" or "not run at all":
     do else stuff
```

or put it this way:

```
if "for clause is not partially run":
    do else stuff
```

or this way:

```
if "for clause not encounter a break":
    do else stuff
```

Comment: else acts as "transaction" in SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another idiomatic use case besides searching. Let's say you wanted to wait for a condition to be true, e.g. a port to be open on a remote server, along with some timeout. Then you could utilize a `while...else` construct like so:

```
import socket
import time

sock = socket.socket()
timeout = time.time() + 15
while time.time() < timeout:
    if sock.connect_ex(('127.0.0.1', 80)) is 0:
        print('Port is open now!')
        break
    print('Still waiting...')
else:
    raise TimeoutError()
```

Answer (score 2):

I was just trying to make sense of it again myself. I found that the following helps!

• Think of the `else` as being paired with the **`if`** inside the loop (instead of with the `for`) - if condition is met then break the loop, else do this - except it's one `else` paired with multiple `if`s!
• If no `if`s were satisfied at all, then do the `else`.
• The multiple `if`s can also actually be thought of as `if`-`elif`s!

Comment: there is no need for an if in the loop, and there's no need for a loop either - you can use else with try-except, for instance

Answer (score 2):

A loop's else branch executes once, regardless of whether the loop enters its body or not, unless the loop body is entered but does not finish. That is, inside the loop a break or return statement is encountered.

```py
my_list = []
for i in my_list:
    print(i, end=',')
else:
    print('loop did not enter')

##################################    

for i in range(1,6,1):
    print(i, end=',')
else:
    print('loop completed successfully:', i)

##################################    

for i in range(1,6,1):
    if i == 3:
        print('loop did not finish:', i)
        break
    print(i, end=',')
else:
    print('else:', i)
```

Output:

```
loop did not enter
1,2,3,4,5,loop completed successfully: 5
1,2,loop did not finish: 3
```

It's the same for while-else.

```py
import random
random.seed(8)

i = 100
while i < 90:
    print(i, end=',')
    i = random.randint(0,100)
else:
    print('loop did not enter:', i)

##################################    

i = 25
while i < 90:
    print(i, end=',')
    i = random.randint(0,100)
else:
    print('loop completed successfully:', i)

##################################    

i = 25
while i < 90:
    if i % 10 == 0:
        print('loop did not finish:', i)
        break
    print(i, end=',')
    i = random.randint(0,100)
else:
    print('else:', i)
```

Output:

```
loop did not enter: 100
25,29,47,48,16,24,loop completed successfully: 90
25,5,loop did not finish: 10
```

Answer (score 2):

It may seems confusing for programmers as we always expect to see `if` when we face an `else`, but in real life we use `else` with `for`

As an example, I ask my son to search the bookshelf for dictionary and bring it to me, and if he can not find it then he should go and buy one for me

This is the `algorithm` in `his` mind

```
for book in bookshelf:
    if book == 'dictionary':
        #Lucky Me !! I find it lets bring it to dad
        bring('dictionary')
        break #and of course I break and stop searching 
else: #too bad :( we do not have any dictionaries
    buy('dictionary');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i)

    if i == 9:
        print("Too big - I'm giving up!")
        break;
else:
    print("Completed successfully")
```

break keyword is used to end the loop. if the i = 9 then the loop will end. while any **if** conditions did not much the satisfaction, then the `else` will do the rest part.

Answer (score 1):

The else clause executes after the loop completes normally. This means The  :==>
**else block just after for/while is executed only when the loop is NOT terminated by a break statement**

```
for item in lista:
if(obj == item ):
    print("if True then break will run and else not run")
    break;
else:
print("in  else => obj not fount ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could think of it like,
`else` as in the rest of the stuff, or the other stuff, that wasn't done in the loop.

Answer (score -2):

I consider the structure as for (if) A else B, and for(if)-else is **a special if-else**, **roughly**. It may help to understand **else**.

A and B is executed at most once, which is the same as if-else structure.

for(if) can be considered as a special if, which does a loop to try to meet the if condition. Once the **if** condition is met, A and **break**; **Else**, B.