# Else statement executing even the IF statement is TRUE

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a problem in **Python** language that is described in a title.

```
 for slovo in slova:
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] and slovo["rect"].collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            for i in range (len(randRijec)):
                if slovo["name"] in randRijec[i]:
                    if i == 0:
                        slovo1 = randRijec[i].upper()
                        prvoSlovo = 1
                    ...
                    ...
                else:
                    pogresnoBrojac += 1
            slova.remove(slovo)
```

So, even this IF statement is **true**, ELSE statement is being executed! However, **else statement** should be skipped if the **if statement** is fulfilled.

How to fix this issue?

p.s. I've had this problem few times before and I was not able to solve it...

Comment: Please include an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Do you mean both blocks are executed or only the else block? Are you sure the indentation is right?

Comment: check your indentation.

Comment: indentation is right, yes, both blocks are being executed

Comment: and why (-1) if the question is asked properly?

thanks btw

Comment: Easily to debunk by adding time.sleep and a "count up" print statement to see at which number in the "for-loop" your "else" triggers (a.k.a. rough debugging). you're answe is far from pythonic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Next solution fixed my problem:

```
    for slovo in slova:
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] and slovo["rect"].collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            xy = 0
            for i in range (len(randRijec)):
                if slovo["name"] in randRijec[i]:
                    xy = 1
                    if i == 0:
                        slovo1 = randRijec[i].upper()
                        prvoSlovo = 1
                        break
                    if i == 1:
                        slovo2 = randRijec[i].upper()
                        drugoSlovo = 1
                        break
            slova.remove(slovo)
            if xy == 0:
                pogresnoBrojac += 1

    ...
    ...
    ...

    xy = 1
    pygame.display.update()
    time.tick(value)
```

So, I have just added that **xy** counter that makes my code work how it should work. When **IF** statement is met, **xy** becomes **1**, if **IF** statement isn't fulfilled, **xy** is set to **0** and then this "**else**" statement executes. At the end of the code, **xy** is set to **1** again to prevent executing this "else" (*if xy == 0*) block.

Answer (score 4):

You have a mixture of tabs and spaces in your code:

Running `cat -A test.py` (on Unix) yields

```
     for slovo in slova:$
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] and slovo["rect"].collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):$
                for i in range (len(randRijec)):$
                    if slovo["name"] in randRijec[i]:$
                        if i == 0:$
                            slovo1 = randRijec[i].upper()$
                            prvoSlovo = 1$
^I^I^I^I^I^I...$
^I^I^I^I^I^I...$
                    else:$
                        pogresnoBrojac += 1$
                slova.remove(slovo)$
```

The `^I` indicate tabs.

Thus, the `else` block is not being interpreted as being at the indentation level on which it *appears* to be.

Your python code should never mix tabs and spaces for indentation. You can check that your script is not mixing tabs and spaces by running `python -t script.py`.

In Python you must commit to using either only spaces or only tabs for indentation. [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) recommends spaces-only indentation.

You can convert tabs to spaces using the [reindent.py program](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Tools/scripts/reindent.py).

Comment: There's no doubt that this is very good advice. However, aren't in this example the `if` and the `else` indented using spaces alone? I am sure I am missing something obvious here.

Comment: thank you for this one, but i can't fix this problem. when I indent it on the right way, I keep getting this issue.

Comment: @NPE: You are right; this may not be the real problem. However, in my experience when the basic rules are conformed to, mysterious errors tend to disappear.

Comment: @lucro93: In that case, you really need to show us runnable code that manifests the problem.

Comment: i found a sollution! i'll answer

Answer (score 3):

> So, even this IF statement is true, ELSE statement is being executed!

I can assure you that this is not what happens.

I notice that in the outline of your code the `if` is inside a `for` loop. Make sure that in your actual code the `else` is not accidentally lined up with the `for` instead of the `if`. I've seen this mistake more than once.

In Python, [`for`-`else` is a valid construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops). For example, the following is perfectly valid Python:

```
for i in range(10):
    if i < 100:
        pass
else:
    print 'In else clause'
```

When run, this prints out `In else clause`.

Contrast this with the following, which doesn't print anything when run:

```
for i in range(10):
    if i < 100:
        pass
    else:
        print 'In else clause'
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but my else statement is lined with the if statement, if you wanted to say that else statement is lined with the for one?

Comment: else is executed in another for-loop. See my main comment at question.

Answer (score 0):

It's a question from a long time ago and I stumbled upon it as I was troubleshooting the very same issue - the solution was actually pretty silly and most probably was also the case - as it's a for loop it iterates through every list element, if even one of those elements doesn't fulfill the if condition, it will automatically trigger the else - pretty self-evident but easy to miss for beginners.
Well at least that was the problem in my case :)