# Else statement executing even if 'if' is true

Tags: python

I've been working on a python script to detect keypresses. It uses the pygame module. My issue is when pressing the up, down and right arrow keys but not the left. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597439/else-statement-executing-even-the-if-statement-is-true) however it does not help me with my problem. The issue is when I press Up, Down or Right it prints the appropriate text and them executes the else statement as well replacing even.unicode with this weird symbol whoever when I press the left arrow key it prints "The key is Left" and no more, like it's supposed to. Also pressing any normal key on the keyboard works fine. Weird HUH. If you can spot the boo boo I've made that would be really great. My code is below, you can copy and paste this into idle for 2.7 if you have pygame installed and see what I mean.

```
#Python key detector, requires pygame module, uses python 2.7
#Import libraries
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *
#Init display
pygame.display.init()
#Infinite loop
while (True):
    #Event detector
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        #If a key is pressed
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == 99:
                sys.exit()
            if event.key == 273:
                print "The key is Up"
            if event.key == 275:
                print "The key is Right"
            if event.key == 274:
                print "The key is Down"
            if event.key == 276:
                print "The key is Left"
            else:
                print "The key is " + event.unicode
```

Comment: I recommend looking into [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), it saves you having long `if` chains. They're easy to use to print back a string, a little more complicated when you're actually going to use them to run code but it is possible using functions.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Well thanks for the suggestion, I must look into them. Sounds like they could save me a bit of time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to use `elif`; otherwise this is just a new check and the `else` statement is executed if the last `if` clause fails.

```
#Event detector
for event in pygame.event.get():
    #If a key is pressed
    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == 99:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.key == 273:
            print "The key is Up"
        elif event.key == 275:
            ...
```

Comment: Thanks, just tried that and it fixed it, I'm new to python so I'm not so sure about everything, thanks for the help :)

Comment: @CuriousProgrammer sadly no points for me :( as it wasn't my answer .. but cheers to Hiro