# Python 3: `else` statement get executed even `if` statement was true

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, argparse

According to previous question [Else statement executing even the IF statement is TRUE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597439/else-statement-executing-even-the-if-statement-is-true) the suggestion provided was to check the indention. Indention seems to be correct in my code. What seems to be the problem?

According to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm

> An else statement can be combined with an if statement. An else
>   statement contains the block of code that executes if the conditional
>   expression in the if statement resolves to 0 or a FALSE value.

As per my understanding, `else` should not be executed if the `if` statement is correct/True.

However, in this code ... `else` statement still get executed .. see `python myCode.py -i 8.8.8.8`

```
C:\Python>python myCode.py
No Argument Provided


C:\Python>python myCode.py -h
usage: myCode.py [-h] [-u URL] [-i IP]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  -u URL, --url URL  Uniform Resource Locator
  -i IP, --ip IP     IP Address


C:\Python>python myCode.py -u google.com
~ URL is google.com


C:\Python>python myCode.py -i 8.8.8.8
~ IP Address is 8.8.8.8
No Argument Provided

C:\Python>
```

This is the code.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-u', '--url',
    help='Uniform Resource Locator' )

parser.add_argument('-i', '--ip',
    help='IP Address' )

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.ip:
    print("~ IP Address is " + args.ip)
if args.url:
    print("~ URL is " + args.url)
else:
    print("No Argument Provided")
```

Please let me know what went wrong here. `No Argument Provided` is not supposed to be there.

```
C:\Python>python myCode.py -i 8.8.8.8
~ IP Address is 8.8.8.8
No Argument Provided
```

Comment: 'else' refers to the last `if`, so if you provide an IP but no URL the else-part is executed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably need to use `elif`. The `else` in your case is executed because `args.url` is empty.

**Ex:**

```
if args.ip:
    print("~ IP Address is " + args.ip)
elif args.url:
    print("~ URL is " + args.url)
else:
    print("No Argument Provided")
```

Comment: Rakesh 's answer is right but besides that, there is a more elegant solution for the underneath problem, see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion