# Python for-else relationship

Tags: python, syntax

I can run the below python script without errors.

```
for n in range(3):
    print n
else:
    print "done"
```

But I am puzzled about the else without a matching if.
It does not make sense.
Can some one explain why this works ?

Comment: Related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops

Comment: Paraphrasing Raymond Hettinger, "if we had just called it `nobreak`, nobody would ever be surprised by it."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `else` clause of `for` and `while` *only executes if the loop exits normally*, i.e. `break` is never run.

```
for i in range(20):
  print i
  if i == 3:
    break
else:
  print 'HAHA!'
```

And the `else` clause of `try` only executes if no exception happened.

```
try:
  a = 1 / 2
except ZeroDivisionError:
  do_something()
else:
  print '/golfclap'
```

Comment: +1 for expanding on the original question by showing how it is used with `try`

Answer (score 3):

The body of the `else` is executed after the `for` loop is done, but only if the `for` loop didn't terminate early by `break` statements.