# Stop the for loop and just get true or false

Tags: python, python-2.7

I make this example code for my problem.
I need to get out just `True` or `False` and stop the loop but i dont know how?

```
def test():
    list = [u"sam", u"jay", u"jean", u"smo", u"gon", u"bil"]
    user = u"jean"
    for x in list:
        if user==x:
            print True
        else:
            print False
test()
```

The output:

```
False
False
True
False
False
False
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just use `in`:

```
def test():
    users = [u"sam", u"jay", u"jean", u"smo", u"gon", u"bil"]
    user = u"jean"
    return user in users
```

Demo:

```
>>> users = [u"sam", u"jay", u"jean", u"smo", u"gon", u"bil"]
>>> user = u"jean"
>>> user in users
True
```

Note that `list` is not a good variable name since it shadows built-in `list`.

---

In case you need a `for` loop, you need to `break` the loop when you hit a match and `print False` in the [`else` block of the `for` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops):

```
def test():
    users = [u"sam", u"jay", u"jean", u"smo", u"gon", u"bil"]
    user = u"jean"
    for x in users:
        if user == x:
            print True
            break
    else:
        print False
```

Comment: no i should use for loop in my code. this is just example for my problem.i need solution for `for loop`

Comment: I try to put `break` but the output print `True` then print `False` but i need when find the correct value print `True` and stop.

Comment: @yuyb0y make sure you run the same code as in the answer - I've tested it before posting.

Comment: While this is the correct usage, I find the Python syntax for `else` with `for` and `while` loops particularly unintuitive. I wish they had used another keyword instead.

Comment: @PeterGibson yeah, it is not a popular programming technique, but it is good to have it in a toolkit.

Answer (score 2):

While alecxe has the best answer, there's one more option: **variables**!

```
def test():
    users = [u"sam", u"jay", u"jean", u"smo", u"gon", u"bil"]
    user = u"jean"

    found = False
    for x in users:
        if user == x:
            found = True;

    print found
```

Comment: I think this is clearer than using the `else` statement with a loop

Answer (score -1):

```
def test():
    list = [u"sam", u"jay", u"jean", u"smo", u"gon", u"bil"]
    user = u"jean"
    for x in list:
        if user==x:
            print True
            break
        else:
            print False
test()
```

You can use break to exit a loop prematurely.

Comment: Note that this will print `"False False True"`.

Answer (score -1):

```
def test():
    list = [u"sam", u"jay", u"jean", u"smo", u"gon", u"bil"]
    user = u"jean"
    for x in list:
        if user==x:
            print True
            return # or return True depending on how you want it to work
                   # break might also be of value here
        else:
            print False
test()
```

Comment: Note that this will print `"False False True"`, and it is __identical__ to Will's answer from 3 hours before you.

Comment: Sorry. Had it open got busy and didn't hit send for a while.