# Python For If Else

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

I just realized that this code does not work the way I hoped it would worked...

```
for i in [0,2,4]:
    if i%2==0:
        print i
else:
    print "There are no EVEN #s"
```

So what's the best way of coding this sort of structure

The idea is to run the "else" statement code if the "if" statement never becomes true through all the iterations of the "for" loop

Comment: If you never `break` (or `return`), the `else` always runs.

Comment: In order to avoid the `else` statement in a `for` loop you need to `break` the loop.  You'd need a state variable that started as `False`, was set to `True` in your conditional block, and then a conditional `break`.

Comment: I ve used that logic before, but just out of curiosity is there another way of using try,except, catch? or something

Comment: @Riddler just add a `break` when you find the first even number. There are other ways of doing this, of course. Also, it would be helpful to *actually include* how you hoped the code would work, and how it works instead.

Comment: You'll need to implement your logic. One way will be to count even numbers first, and check count after the loop. Or you can set flag when even number is found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code doesn't work as you would like it to because the `if` and `else` are not on the same level of scope. However, there is a `for...else` syntax in Python that you were perhaps trying to use. For information on that, see [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops). To use the `for...else` syntax, you need to have a `break` statement inside the `for` loop. If it breaks, then the `else` is not called, otherwise the `else` be called after the loop is done.

However, if you don't have a `break` statement, then `else` always runs.

Here is your code, corrected:

```
for i in [0,2,4]:
    if i%2==0:
        print i
        break
else:
    print "There are no EVEN #s"
```

As soon as the loop encounters an even number, the loop breaks. Otherwise, if the loop would fully execute (i.e. go through the entire list), then it would also run the `else`. Just for reference, here is the loop on a list of odd numbers:

```
for i in [1,3,5]:
    if i%2==0:
        print i
        break
else:
    print "There are no EVEN #s"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that a more "pythonic" approach would be to filter the list and check if the filtered list has any elements to figure out what to print:

```
lst = [0, 2, 4]
filtered = [x for x in lst if x%2 == 0]
if filtered:
    for item in filtered:
        print item
else:
    print "No evens"
```

Answer (score 1):

just set a flag in the if statement that you can check after the for loop is finished running.

e.g.

```
flag = False
for i in [0,2,4]:
    if i%2==0:
        print i
        flag = True

if not flag:
    print "There is an ODD #"
```

Comment: It'd probably be more pythonic to let `flag = True` in the start, and in the `if` statement in the loop set `flag = False`, so then in the final `if` statement you can have `if flag` instead of `if not flag`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if any even numbers exist and don't care about the value use [any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
if any(i % 2 == 0 for i in [0,2,4,5]):
        print "The list has even numbers"          
else:
    print "There are no EVEN #s"
```

`any` will evaluate lazily returning True as soon as any even number is found or False if the list contains no even numbers.

Comment: That's a nice solution.

Comment: @Newb,thanks,  might not be what the OP desires but a nice thing to learn about and will be useful at some stage no doubt.

Comment: Yup, it might be arguably not quite on topic, but at least I learned something new.