# How to use For Else if you want the for loop to always finish?

Tags: python

[I was looking at this SO question about the Python For Else flow control and I thought I had a portion of code that which is very close to the example given.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-) I think that my code is very close to the example code except that I want the for loop to finish (for logging purposes).

```
for module_name, class_name in BASIC_PARSERS_TO_RUN:
    full_module_name = "parsers." + module_name
    parser = getattr(import_module(full_module_name), class_name)(
        logger=logger)
    parser_data = parser.parse(cluster_path)

    if parser_data is None or parser_data == "0":
        # Basic None instead of "None" so that json is serialized to null
        # instead of "None"
        json_data_list.append({module_name: parser_data})
        failed_basic_checks = True
    else:
        json_data_list.append({module_name: str(parser_data)})

# Checking if we have a valid data set.
if failed_basic_checks:
    json_data_list.append({"basic_validation_succeeded": False})
    return json.dumps(json_data_list)
    # We've run into a dataset which isn't valid.
    exit(1)
```

Is there any way to change my for loop to use the for else flow control?

```
found_obj = None
for obj in objects:
    if obj.key == search_key:
        found_obj = obj
        break
else:
    print 'No object found.'
```

Comment: You can't guarantee your loop will always finish if you have an if-statement with a break inside that loop (unless you have something like `if 1 == 2:1). You can of course *always* uese the `else` clause by just leaving it out. Then, "No object found." will always be printed, no mattter whether a matching key was found or not.

Comment: Your question seems unclear; what is the larger context of your question? What do you want to achieve with always using the `else` clause.

Comment: If you always want your loop to run to completion, then you probably don't want any `break` statements in the loop.  If there are no `break` statements in the loop, then the point of having the `else` construct isn't clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code as written is just fine; there's no reason to use a `for`/`else` structure.

According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops), an `else` after a loop is always executed unless the loop was terminated by a `break` statement.  So if you are not using `break` statements in the loop, an `else` clause is unnecessary; you should simply put the relevant code after the loop.

Comment: .. only executed if the loop was *not* terminated by a `break` statement.