# Python if statement delay

Tags: python, if-statement, raspberry-pi, delay, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to make a 'game' while learning about both Python and GPIO on the Raspberry Pi. This is what I have ATM:

```
while playing == 1:
        if (GPIO.input(9) == 0):
            GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)
            print("Well done!!")
            time.sleep(1)
        else:    
            print("Wrong!")
            lives = lives - 1
            time.sleep(1)
        playing = 0
```

Now, my problem is that the program is hitting the if statement and is going straight to the else (as you would expect), however, I want the program to wait on the first part of the if statement for a second, then go to the else.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I might be misunderstanding something. You want that code to wait for 1 second before running the `if/else` block? Because if that's the case, it's just a matter of putting the `time.sleep(1)` right before the `if` (or right under the `while playing == 1:`, but this is probably not that what you want, right?

Comment: You need to state the question more clearly. In doing so, you may even solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could rewrite it like so:

```
while playing == 1:
   for _ in range(10):
       if GPIO.input(9) == 0:
           GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)
           print("Well done!!")
           break
       time.sleep(0.1)
   else:    
       print("Wrong!")
       lives = lives - 1
```

This polls the GPIO pin ten times 100ms apart. The `else` is hit if the GPIO pin stays high throughout the ten attempts.

(If you haven't come across Python's `for`-`else` construct, see [Why does python use 'else' after for and while loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops).)

Alternatively, you could use `GPIO` module's more advanced features, such as edge detection and callbacks. See the [documentation](http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/).