# How to generate all permutations of splitting an array to two subarrays in Scala?

Tags: scala

Given an array, I would like to split it into two non-empty subarrays.

For example, given the following array:

`val nums = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)`

I would like to generate the following unique permutations:

```
(Array(1), Array(2, 3, 4))
(Array(2), Array(1, 3, 4))
(Array(1, 2), Array(3, 4))
(Array(3), Array(1, 2, 4))
(Array(1, 3), Array(2, 4))
(Array(2, 3), Array(1, 4))
(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(4))
```

The permutations are unique in the sense that if a given split is just a mirror of another split, I only need to keep one of them. Also, the order of elements in the subarrays do *not* matter.

See below for a working solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57262577/5767875. 
But I believe a more elegant and functional solution exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def splits(xs: Array[Int]): Array[(Array[Int], Array[Int])] = {
  val startSplit: Array[(Array[Int], Array[Int])] = Array((Array(xs.head), Array.empty))
  xs.tail.foldLeft(startSplit) { (splits, x) =>
    splits.flatMap {
      case (left, right) => Array((x +: left, right), (left, x +: right))
    }
  }.tail
}
```

The basic idea is that if you know all of the splits for the first N elements, then there are twice as many splits for N+1 elements: you can add the new element to either the left or the right for every split and obtain a new split. That's what's happening in the `foldLeft` call.

The only small wrinkles are: this would generate "mirror" splits, so the starting point just always has the first element on the left. And: at the end you have one extra output which is every element on the left, so the final call to `.tail` gets rid of that.

Note that the performance of this is probably pretty horrible, since scala arrays don't have efficient appends and such so every operation makes a copy. You could replace `Array` with `List` in the above code and get something better. If you really need to deal with arrays you could then just convert (`.toList` / `.toArray`)

Comment: Very nice solution, @Joe K! You are right using `List` can speed up the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29656792/5767875), below is a version of Scala code:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

def generateSplitPermutations(nums: Array[Int]): Array[(Array[Int], Array[Int])] = {
  var results: List[(Array[Int], Array[Int])] = List()

  var flags = Array.fill(nums.length)(false)
  var done = false
  while (!done) {

    var a = ArrayBuffer[Int]()
    var b = ArrayBuffer[Int]()
    for ((bool, i) <- flags.zipWithIndex) {
      if (bool)
        a += nums(i)
      else
        b += nums(i)
    }

    if (a.length > 0 && b.length > 0) {
       results = results :+ (a.toArray, b.toArray)
    }

    if (flags.map(x => if (x) 1 else 0).sum == nums.length / 2 + 1) {
      done = true
    }

    // if done is true, the following code block won't matter
    var ok = false
    for (i <- 0 until nums.length if !ok) {
      flags(i) = !flags(i)
      if (flags(i))
        ok = true
    }
  }

  results.toArray
}
```

```
val nums = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
generateSplitPermutations(nums)
```

outputs:

```
scala> generateSplitPermutations(nums)
res16: Array[(Array[Int], Array[Int])] = Array((Array(1),Array(2, 3, 4)), (Array(2),Array(1, 3, 4)), (Array(1, 2),Array(3, 4)), (Array(3),Array(1, 2, 4)), (Array(1, 3),Array(2, 4)), (Array(2, 3),Array(1, 4)), (Array(1, 2, 3),Array(4)))
```

Is there a more Scala/functional way of achieving this?