# python code trying to find prime number. Code is counting not prime number. Can't find why

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging

I am trying to find every prime number in a user chosen range,  list them and count them. my code counts and list number that are not prime. I really can't find why? Could somebody please help me.

```
print("This code will count how many prime number exist in a certain range")
count = 0
lower = int(input("Enter lower range: "))
upper = int(input("Enter upper range: "))
prime = []
for num in range(lower, upper + 1):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2,num):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                break
            else:
                prime.append(num)
                break
print(prime)
print("There are", len(prime), "prime number between", lower, "and", upper)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here,

```
    for i in range(2,num):
        if (num % i) == 0:    #If num is divisible by SOME i, it is not prime. Correct.
            break
        else:                 #If num is not divisible by SOME i, it is not prime. WRONG.
            prime.append(num)
            break
```

You should have checked the condition like this : `If num is not divisible by ANY i, it is prime`.

With minimum changes using else with for,

```
    for i in range(2,num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            break
    else:
        prime.append(num)
```

---

Read more : [Why does python use 'else' after for and while loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops)

Answer (score 1):

Your primes part is wrong.  I'm going to abstract that to a different method to make it easier.  To be prime, a `n%x` must hold up for any `x` such that `x` is in the set of numbers `[2,ceil(sqrt(n))]`.

**Make sure you `import math`**

```
def is_prime(num):
    for i in range(2, math.ceil(num**(1/2))):
        if num%i==0:
            return False
    return True
```

Then, just replace

```
if num > 1:
    for i in range(2,num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            break
        else:
            prime.append(num)
            break
```

With,

```
if num>1:
   if is_prime(num):
      prime.append(num)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you dont wait all division checks to append the number to primes list:

```
            if (num % i) == 0:
                break
            else:
                prime.append(num)
                break
```

The fix for your code:

```
        is_prime =True
        for i in range(2,num):
            if num % i == 0:
                is_prime = False
                break

        if is_prime:
            prime.append(num)
```

---

```
$ python prime_test.py 
This code will count how many prime number exist in a certain range
Enter lower range: 12
Enter upper range: 20
[13, 17, 19]
('There are', 3, 'prime number between', 12, 'and', 20)
```

Comment: To be a prime, all modulus num % i should not equal to zero.  2%2==0.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to get the prime number form a list. Ask user for range between the prime number should be created and store it in `list`:

```py
list4=list(range(3,10,1))  
prime_num=[x for x in list4 if x%2!=0 and x%3!=0]
```