# Understanding another's text-mining function that removes similar strings

Tags: python, r, dictionary, nlp, tm

I’m trying to replicate the methodology from this article, [538 Post about Most Repetitive Phrases](http://fivethirtyeight.com/features/these-are-the-phrases-each-gop-candidate-repeats-most/), in which the author mined US presidential debate transcripts to determine the most repetitive phrases for each candidate.

I'm trying to implement this methodology with another dataset in R with the `tm` package.

Most of the code ([GitHub repository](https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/data/blob/master/repeated-phrases-gop/robopol2.py)) concerns mining the transcripts and assembling counts of each ngram, but I get lost at the `prune_substrings()` function code below:

```
def prune_substrings(tfidf_dicts, prune_thru=1000):

    pruned = tfidf_dicts

    for candidate in range(len(candidates)):
        # growing list of n-grams in list form
        so_far = []

        ngrams_sorted = sorted(tfidf_dicts[candidate].items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:prune_thru]
        for ngram in ngrams_sorted:
            # contained in a previous aka 'better' phrase
            for better_ngram in so_far:
                if overlap(list(better_ngram), list(ngram[0])):
                    #print "PRUNING!! "
                    #print list(better_ngram)
                    #print list(ngram[0])

                    pruned[candidate][ngram[0]] = 0
            # not contained, so add to so_far to prevent future subphrases
            else:
                so_far += [list(ngram[0])]

    return pruned
```

The input of the function, `tfidf_dicts`, is an array of dictionaries (one for each candidate) with ngrams as keys and tf-idf scores as values. For example, Trump's tf-idf dict begins like this:

```
trump.tfidf.dict = {'we don't win': 83.2, 'you have to': 72.8, ... }
```

so the structure of the input is like this:

```
tfidf_dicts = {trump.tfidf.dict, rubio.tfidf.dict, etc }
```

MY understanding is that `prune_substrings` does the following things, but I'm stuck on the `else if` clause, which is a pythonic thing I don't understand yet.

> A.    create list : pruned as tfidf_dicts; a list of tfidf dicts for each candidate
>
> B loop through each candidate:
>
> 1. so_far = start an empty list of ngrams gone through so so_far
> 2. ngrams_sorted = sorted member's tf-idf dict from smallest to biggest
> 3. loop through each ngram in sorted
>
>    - loop through each better_ngram in so_far
>
>      1. IF overlap b/w (below) == TRUE:
>
>         - better_ngram (from so_far) and
>         - ngram (from ngrams_sorted)
>         - THEN zero out tf-idf for ngram
>      2. ELSE if (WHAT?!?)
>
>         - add ngram to list, so_far
>
> C. return pruned, i.e. list of unique ngrams sorted in order

Any help at all is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 months later but here's my solution. I'm sure there is a more efficient solution, but for my purposes, it worked. The pythonic for-else doesn't translate to R. So the steps are different.

1. Take top `n` ngrams.
2. Create a list, `t`, where each element of the list is a logical vector of length `n` that says whether ngram in question overlaps  all other ngrams (but fix 1:x to be false automatically)
3. Cbind together every element of `t` into a table, `t2`
4. Return only elements of `t2` row sum is zero
   set elements 1:n to FALSE (i.e. no overlap)

Ouala!

### PrunedList Function

```
#' GetPrunedList
#' 
#' takes a word freq df with columns Words and LenNorm, returns df of nonoverlapping strings
GetPrunedList <- function(wordfreqdf, prune_thru = 100) {
        #take only first n items in list
        tmp <- head(wordfreqdf, n = prune_thru) %>%
                select(ngrams = Words, tfidfXlength = LenNorm)
        #for each ngram in list:
        t <- (lapply(1:nrow(tmp), function(x) {
                #find overlap between ngram and all items in list (overlap = TRUE)
                idx <- overlap(tmp[x, "ngrams"], tmp$ngrams)
                #set overlap as false for itself and higher-scoring ngrams
                idx[1:x] <- FALSE
                idx
        }))
        
        #bind each ngram's overlap vector together to make a matrix
        t2 <- do.call(cbind, t)   
        
        #find rows(i.e. ngrams) that do not overlap with those below
        idx <- rowSums(t2) == 0
        pruned <- tmp[idx,]
        rownames(pruned) <- NULL
        pruned
}
```

### Overlap function

```
#' overlap
#' OBJ: takes two ngrams (as strings) and to see if they overlap
#' INPUT: a,b ngrams as strings
#' OUTPUT: TRUE if overlap
overlap <- function(a, b) {
        max_overlap <- min(3, CountWords(a), CountWords(b))
        
        a.beg <- word(a, start = 1L, end = max_overlap)
        a.end <- word(a, start = -max_overlap, end = -1L)
        b.beg <- word(b, start = 1L, end = max_overlap)
        b.end <- word(b, start = -max_overlap, end = -1L)
        
        # b contains a's beginning
        w <- str_detect(b, coll(a.beg, TRUE))
        # b contains a's end
        x <- str_detect(b, coll(a.end, TRUE))
        # a contains b's beginning
        y <- str_detect(a, coll(b.beg, TRUE))
        # a contains b's end
        z <- str_detect(a, coll(b.end, TRUE))
        
        #return TRUE if any of above are true
        (w | x | y | z)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note the indentation in your code... The `else` is lined up with the second `for`, not the `if`. This is a `for-else` construct, not an `if-else`.

In that case, the `else` is being used to initialize the inner loop, because it will be executed when `so_far` is empty the first time through, and each time the inner loop runs out of items to iterate through...

I am not sure that this is the most efficient way to achieve these comparisons, but conceptually you can get a sense of the flow with this snippet:

```
s=[]
for j in "ABCD":
   for i in s:
      print i,
   else:
       print "\nelse"
       s.append(j)
```

Output:

```
else
A 
else
A B 
else
A B C 
else
```

I would think that in R there is a much better way to do this than nested loops....

Comment: Your snippet was especially helpful for me. For reference, [This on SO Answer to "Why does python use 'else' after for and while loops?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9980160/3842610), gives a more in depth explanation.

Comment: @AndersSwanson in the back of my mind, I wonder if there is an off-by-one error in their script, since in my toy example D is not printed. Is it tested in theirs..?