# Python for..else loop always triggers else

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, for-loop

I am trying to read a tab-separated file and collect all characters except control characters. If a control character is hit, the remainder of line should be ignored too.
I've tried the following code in Python 3.5, using a [`for..else` loop](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops):

```
import curses.ascii

input_file = ...
chars = set()
with open(input_file) as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        source, target = line.split("\t")

        for c in source.strip() + target.strip():
            if curses.ascii.iscntrl(c):
                print("Control char hit.")
                break
            chars.add(c)
        else:
            print("Line contains control character:\n" + line)
            continue

        print("Line contains no control character:\n" + line.strip())
```

I'd expect this to check each character for being a control character and if it hits one (`break` is triggered), skip to the next line, hence trigger the `else`/`continue` statement.

What happens instead is that `continue` is always triggered, even if the `break` statement in the `if` clause is never reached for a line. Consequently, the final `print` statement is never reached either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the else is triggered only when break is not triggered.

Comment: Hmmm, I suggest you read more about the `for...else` in python: [How can I make sense of the `else` statement in Python loops?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642573/how-can-i-make-sense-of-the-else-statement-in-python-loops/37643358#37643358)

Comment: Check this out if it helps  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops

Comment: Thanks to all of you, your hints have helped. I find the terminology somewhat confusing though.

Comment: If you try to pair `else` with for, it could be confusing. I don't think the keyword else was a great choice for this syntax, But if you pair else with break, you can see it actually makes sense.

Let me show how it works in human language. --
`for` each person in a group of suspects `if` anyone is the criminal `break` the investigation. `else` report failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `else` block of a `for` loop is *only* executed if the `for` loop never was interrupted. You'll only see the `continue` statement in the `else` block executed if there were *no control characters in the line*. From the [`for` statement documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement):

> When the items are exhausted (which is immediately when the sequence is empty or an iterator raises a `StopIteration` exception), the suite in the `else` clause, if present, is executed, and the loop terminates.
>
> A `break` statement executed in the first suite terminates the loop without executing the `else` clause’s suite.

A better test to see if there are control characters in a line is to use the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
if any(curses.ascii.iscntrl(c) for c in source.strip() + target.strip()):
    print("Line contains control character:\n" + line)
    continue
```

or you could use a regular expression; this'll be faster as the looping over text is done in C code without having to box each individual character in a new `str` object:

```
import re

control_char = re.compile(r'[\x00-\x31]')

if control_char.search(source.strip() + target.strip()):
    print("Line contains control character:\n" + line)
    continue
```