# Unable to return the first even number from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I understand placing even numbers in a new list but when there are a number of odd numbers in front I can only seem to call -1? and for an empty string I receive 'nothing' when it should also return -1

```
def first_even(items):
    """ (list of int) -> int

    Return the first even number from items. Return -1 if items     contains no even numbers.

    >>> first_even([1, 9, 3, 77, 13, 5, 8])
    8
    >>> first_even([7, 1])
    -1
    """
    even = []
    for num in items:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            even.append(num)
        else:
            return -1
    return even[0]
```

Comment: Put `return -1` outside the loop and `return num` instead of appending

Answer (score 2):

```
def first_even(items):
    """ (list of int) -> int

    Return the first even number from items. Return -1 if items     contains no even numbers.

    >>> first_even([1, 9, 3, 77, 13, 5, 8])
    8
    >>> first_even([7, 1])
    -1
    """
    for num in items:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            return num
    return -1
```

Answer (score 1):

The `else` block will be executed for the first odd number, this will terminate the `for` and discard all previous *appends*. Instead you want to return the even number as soon as it is found (you don't need the list) and then move the `else` to align with the `for` or outside the `for`:

```
def first_even(items):
    for num in items:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            return num
    else:
        return -1
    # or put the default value to return here
```

---

Reference for Python `for/else` block:

[How can I make sense of the `else` clause of Python loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642573/how-can-i-make-sense-of-the-else-statement-in-python-loops/37643358#37643358)

Comment: wrong! you can't have an 'else' without an 'if' at the same indentation level

Comment: @user4421975 Hahaha, I bet you are new to Python. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/37643358/3125566

Comment: The else is actually redundant.  The only point of adding it would be if the `return num` was a `break`, you cannot return from a function twice

Comment: @PadraicCunningham But `return num` does nearly the same thing as a `break` except that it returns control to the caller. Looks more like returning from an `else` branch when the `if` is not executed.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye, I am not quite sure I follow, removing the else and putting the return outside the loop would behave exactly the same.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, it would. I did this in keeping with OP's use of `else`, but it does look like an *overkill*

Comment: Ah ok, I thought you meant there was some actual difference in execution.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye, you blew my mind. Would you believe I have 3 years experience in python  and I didn't know that is possible?

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, your `else` case is causing premature termination, and the use of a `list` is rather pointless. You could fix all this, see the other answers for minimalist fixes, but there is another option: Let Python built-ins do more of the work for you.

[The `next` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) will return the first item from an iterator, and with a second argument, if the iterator is empty, it returns the second argument instead. So give it a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression) that lazily produces all the even numbers in the input, and it will pull the first one and return it. If none are found, the default case will return `-1` for you:

```
def first_even(items):
    # x & 1 == 0 is roughly equivalent and might be slightly faster
    return next((x for x in items if x % 2 == 0), -1)
```

For the pathological sorts, this might be slightly faster, but it's far less intuitive to people who don't already know Python internals inside and out; I don't recommend it:

```
from itertools import filterfalse  # ifilterfalse on Py2

def first_even(items):
    # (1).__rand__ is roughly equivalent, and may be faster
    return next(filterfalse((2).__rmod__, items), -1)
```

Comment: Or `if not x % 2` which would be slightly faster

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: True. My instinct is actually to write `not x % 2`, but I try to avoid it in SO answers since the test for `0` is describing the mathematical test more directly, and the performance difference is roughly 5-10 ns per test. :-)

Comment: I hate typing so that is my excuse ;) You could also `not x & 1` :)