# Dangling else in Python - else not aligned properly with if

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

How does the code work even though the else statement is not aligned with the preceding if statement?

```
ret_code = -1
MAX_COUNT = 3
if ret_code < 0:
            for i in range(MAX_COUNT-1):
                print("sleep")
                ret_code = 4
                if ret_code >= 5:
                    break
            else:
                print(ret_code, '', 'Error')
```

Output is as follows:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux

sleep
sleep
4  Error
```

How does this work?

Comment: See also: [How can I make sense of the `else` clause of Python loops?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642573/how-can-i-make-sense-of-the-else-clause-of-python-loops/37643358#37643358)

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: now you can add other duplicates (since last week). I added yours. Super-nice gold badge feature. Use it!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Just learning that from you. Sweet :)

Comment: This is all very helpful, I was not aware of the the for-else clause in Python and did not know what to look for. Thanks! @Jean-FrançoisFabre