# Why is my code slower when I try to memoize?

Tags: python, primes, memoization

I have a function that lists the prime numbers smaller than N:

```
def ListPrimes(N):
    list = [2]
    for n in range(3, N, 2):
        for i in range(3, int(sqrt(n)+1)):
            if n % i == 0:
                break
        else:
            list.append(n)
    return list
```

I tried to make it faster, so I changed one line to the following:

```
def ListPrimesFaster(N):
   list = [2]
   for n in range(3, N, 2):
        for i in list:
            if n % i == 0:
                break
        else:
            list.append(n)
    return list
```

I was surprised that the second version is at least 5 times slower, given that it is identical to the first except that the variable i has to iterate through a shorter list.

I am trying to find a faster way to list prime numbers smaller than some N.

Comment: Significantly faster way is sieve of Eratosthenes

Comment: How exactly did you perform your measurements BTW?

Comment: @barakmanos, the indentation is correct and the second snippet functions correctly, albiet slower.

Comment: @KevinW.: Well, I must be missing something here. What `if` does this `else` correspond to?

Comment: @barakmanos http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks. I am embarrassed to say that I've never seen this construct before (nor could I imagine that the "pedantic" Python standard would even allow it). At least I found some comfort in the opening statement of the accepted answer on that link - "It's a strange construct even to seasoned Python coders". Anyhow, it's good to learn new tricks I suppose (though I doubt that I'd ever use it due to the ambiguity IMO).

Comment: @KevinW.: Thanks, see comment above...

Comment: Put `print` statements in both loops, you'll see that `ListPrimesFaster()` has more iterations of the inner loop, not fewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListPrimesFaster()` doesn't search through a shorter list, because it includes elements in `list` that are higher than `sqrt(n)`. The size of `list` grows faster than `sqrt(n)`, and starting the range at 3 saves a few steps as well. `ListPrimes(100)` performs `139` `n % i == 0` tests, while `ListPrimesFaster(100)` does `362`. When `N` is `500`, the test counts are `1616` versus `4933`.

BTW, in `ListPrimes()`, the inner loop only needs to test odd factors, since `n` is always odd, so you could change it to:

```
for i in range(3, int(sqrt(n)+1), 2):
```

This simple change drops the number of tests to `87` for `N = 100`, and `907` for `N = 500`.

Comment: Yes, thank you. That was silly of me I can't believe I missed it! I added a condition to exit the loop once i reach a number larger than sqrt(n) and it runs much faster now.