# Need Help in Python if..for..else Loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, for-else

I'm new to programming and have found this if...for...else Loop, please help me understand it:

```
if(True):
    for i in range(0, 1):
        print i
    else:
        print 'x'
```

[written in Python 2.7] Which gives an Output:

```
0
1
```

This seems like it executes both the for loop and the else loop, but only else loop is not allowed. Why? What is the difference between this and the normal if...else loop?

Comment: Hmm, duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/9979970/2301450?

Comment: There’s an `if` statement, **and** a [for...else... statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops), they’re not together as you can tell from the level of indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `for - else` loop. It executes the code in the `for` loop and if it completes normally it then executes the `else` clause. If however there is a `break` in the loop it is going to terminate it and not execute the `else` clause.

You can read more about it here: http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html