# Python3 How to join two lists of dicts by unique keys

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have two lists:

```
list1 = [ {'sth': 13, 'important_key1': 'AA', 'important_key2': '3'}, {'oh!': 14, 'important_key1': 'FF', 'important_key2': '4'}, {'sth_else': 'abc', 'important_key1': 'ZZ', 'important_key2': '5'}]
list2 = [ {'why-not': 'tAk', 'important_key1': 'GG', 'important_key2': '4'}, {'hmmm': 'no', 'important_key1': 'AA', 'important_key2': '3'}]
```

I want to return a list with objects only from list1 but if the same `important_key1` and `important_key2` is in any element in list2 I want this element from list2.

So the output should be:

```
[ {'hmmm': 'no', 'important_key1': 'AA', 'important_key2': '3'}, {'oh!': 14, 'important_key1': 'FF', 'important_key2': '4'}, {'sth_else': 'abc', 'important_key1': 'ZZ', 'important_key2': '5'}]
```

It is not complicated to do it by two or three loops but I wonder whether there is a simple way by using list comprehensions or something like that.

This is the "normal" way:

```
list1 = [ {'sth': 13, 'important_key1': 'AA', 'important_key2': '3'}, {'oh!': 14, 'important_key1': 'FF', 'important_key2': '4'}]
list2 = [ {'hmmm': 'no', 'important_key1': 'AA', 'important_key2': '3'}, {'why-not': 'tAk', 'important_key1': 'GG', 'important_key2': '4'}]

final_list = []
for element in list1:
    there_was_in_list2 = False
    for another_element in list2:
        if element['important_key1'] == another_element['important_key1'] and element['important_key2'] == another_element['important_key2']:
            final_list.append(another_element)
            there_was_in_list2 = True
            break
    if not there_was_in_list2:
        final_list.append(element)
print(final_list)
```

is there any Pythonic way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert `list2` to a dict indexed by a tuple of the values the important keys in `list2`, and then use it to determine if the same keys in `list1` have the same values as you iterate through `list1` in a list comprehension, so that the time complexity gets reduced to O(n) from your O(n*m):

```
keys = ['important_key1', 'important_key2']
d2 = {tuple(d[k] for k in keys): d for d in list2[::-1]}
print([d2.get(tuple(d[k] for k in keys), d) for d in list1])
```

This outputs (with your sample input):

`[{'hmmm': 'no', 'important_key1': 'AA', 'important_key2': '3'}, {'oh!': 14, 'important_key1': 'FF', 'important_key2': '4'}, {'sth_else': 'abc', 'important_key1': 'ZZ', 'important_key2': '5'}]`

As you described in your question, only `{'sth': 13, 'important_key1': 'AA', 'important_key2': '3'}` in `list1` would get replaced by `{'hmmm': 'no', 'important_key1': 'AA', 'important_key2': '3'}` because only this dict has both `important_key1` and `important_key2` matching those of a dict in `list2`.

Comment: it doesn't work in two cases: one list is not sorted so element with the same values for important_key1 and important_key2 may be somewhere else. Second case is that these two lists don't have to be the same length.

Comment: I will add this to my example

Comment: Can you update your question with the inputs and expected outputs for these two cases? It isn't clear from your description what the outputs would be here.

Comment: Updated my answer with your new input then.

Comment: Clearly this answer's code is different than the one from the OP. Here the two lists are zipped while in the OP they are nested.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect your new input then.

Comment: It doesn't work on my production code and I don't know why yet. It seems to work for any cases which I can imagine but when I have many, many value there must be something different :( I will check it tomorrow.

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz It is because the code does something else than you have in mind. While you indicated a product between the two lists (i.e. nested for) this code just zips the lists together and hence will only check one element in `list2` for each element in `list1` (instead of scanning through the whole of `list2`).

Comment: I've updated my answer so that dicts in `list1` would get replaced by any dict in `dict2` that matches both important keys, as opposed to my previous answer, which would only match if the dict in `list1` and the dict in `list2` are of the same index in their respective lists. Please try again.

Comment: @blhsing It's still not correct since you are taking the last match out of `list2` instead of the first (compare with OP).

Comment: @a_guest You're right but it wasn't so hard to reverse the data and it works for me so it will accept this answer.

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz Sure, this is probably the best answer, considering the improvement in time complexity. Since SO is a Q/A site it is important that answers really answer the actual question. @ blhsing I have applied the corresponding edit.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
list1 = [{'sth': 13, 'important_key1': 'AA', 'important_key2': '3'}, {'oh!': 14, 'important_key1': 'FF', 'important_key2': '4'}]
list2 = [{'hmmm': 'no', 'important_key1': 'AA', 'important_key2': '3'}, {'why-not': 'tAk', 'important_key1': 'GG', 'important_key2': '4'}]
vals = ['important_key1', 'important_key2']
new_list = [[c if any(c[a] == i[a] for a in vals) else i for c in list2] for i in list1]
final_result = [i[0] for i in new_list if i]
```

Output:

```
[{'hmmm': 'no', 'important_key1': 'AA', 'important_key2': '3'}, {'oh!': 14, 'important_key1': 'FF', 'important_key2': '4'}]
```

Comment: it is not my output. Check "So the output should be:" again :)

Comment: Dicts which are not in list2 should still be in the output list.

Comment: Wrapping everything in list comprehensions just because you can is not pythonic at all. Especially for more complicated tasks like this one it really makes the code more difficult to read and hence to maintain. [Readability counts.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: it doesn't work in two cases: one list is not sorted so element with the same values for important_key1 and important_key2 may be somewhere else. Second case is that these two lists don't have to be the same length.

Comment: I will add this to my example

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz As blhsing pointed out below, the rules for producing the desired output are not clear. See [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Ajax1234 I don't understand why it is not clear. I even gave example of working code but I thought it is just a little too long. If there is any doubt this code should cleared up.

Answer (score 1):

You can spare the `there_was_in_list2` variable by using [`for...else`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9979970/3767239). The `else` statement will be executed when the previous `for` loop finished normally (i.e. it was not "broken").

```
final_list = []
for element in list1:
    for another_element in list2:
        if element['important_key1'] == another_element['important_key1'] and element['important_key2'] == another_element['important_key2']:
            final_list.append(another_element)
            break
    else:
        final_list.append(element)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your code to be more concise yet maintain readability you can replace the second for loop with a combined `next` and `filter`:

```
final_list.append(next(
    filter(lambda x: ..., list2),
    element  # Default in case filter yields nothing.
))
```

Answer (score 1):

Most all other paths are covered so here is another idea, just coming up with as many possible routes we can, this was fun btw thank you :)

```
l3 = l1[:]

for idx, item in enumerate(l2):    
    for x, i in enumerate(l1):
        k = list(zip(item.values(), i.values())) 
        if len(set(k[1])) < len(k[1]) and len(set(k[2])) < len(k[2]):
            l3[x] = item

print(l3)
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow/sept$ python3.7 uniq.py
> [{'hmmm': 'no', 'important_key1': 'AA', 'important_key2': '3'}, {'oh!':14, 'important_key1': 'FF', 'important_key2': '4'},
> {'sth_else': 'abc', 'important_key1': 'ZZ', 'important_key2': '5'}]
> ```