# Finding element from one list in nested second list

Tags: python

I have two lists with string values, `list1 = ['a','g','f','e']` and `list2 = [['c','v','d'], ['a','d','e'], ['g','h']]`. I want to write a code, that will append `list1` into `list2` only if first (0th) element in nested list of list2 is  not the same as first (0th) element from `list1`.

This is the code that I wrote, it does not have errors, but It does not do what I want

```
list1 = ['a','g','f','e']
list2 = [['c','v','d'], ['a','d','e'], ['g','h']]

print('List 1: ', list1)
print('List 2: ', list2)

for nest in list2:
    if list1[0] != nest[0]:
        list2.append(list1)
        print(list2)        
    else:
        print("Not added")
```

Comment: What's the expected output of `list2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```
list1 = ['a','g','f','e']
list2 = [['c','v','d'], ['a','d','e'], ['g','h']]

print("List 1: ", list1)
print("List 2: ", list2)

for nested_list in list2:
    if nested_list[0] == list1[0]:
        print("Not added")
        break
else:
    list2.append(list1)

print(list2)
```

The `else` block after the `for` loop is executed, if the loop finished without `break`. You can read more about `for`-`else` at [Why does python use 'else' after for and while loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops) for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) to check if all first elements of the sublists are not the same as the first element of `list1`:

```
if all(l[0] != list1[0] for l in list2):
    list2.append(list1)
```