# Why is for else allowed in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I don't understand why this is allowed in python?

```
>>> for i in []:
...   print(i)
... else:
...   print('here')
...
here
```

should this not have else without if syntax error? The else operates every time too (if the for has iterated or not) so its not connected.

```
>>> for i in 1,2,3:
...   print(i)
... else:
...   print('here')
...
1
2
3
here
```

Comment: Your example shows the `else` **not** operating every time. Have you read e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops? Or e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/9979970/3001761? What do you mean *"why"*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the **[docs](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html)**

*** The else clause executes after the loop completes normally. This means that the loop did not encounter a break statement.***

So this is useful if you are doing a for loop but do not know if the element will be found in the loop/ returned true in the loop. So you can add a break statement to exit the loop if the element is found/true, or execute another command if it is not found/true. For example in your loop:

```
for i in []:
  print(i)
else:
 print('here')
```

**Output**

```
here
```

In this case, i was not found in your for loop. However you did not execute a break statement after the for loop. Because of that, the compiler then goes to the `else` statement to executes the line(s) there since the for loop did not break.

In the second example you have:

```
for i in 1,2,3:
  print(i)
else:
  print('here')
```

**Output**

```
1
2
3
here
```

The for loop did not encounter a break statement, so after the for loop is completed it will then execute the else clause. However it you were to use:

```
for i in 1,2,3:
    print(i)
    break
 else:
    print('here')
```

**Output** :

```
1
```

Answer (score 3):

`else` is executed if we don't `break` from `for`.

This can be useful in situation and can help us by saving us from the effort of making flags.

Example:

if we want to execute some code if we don't break from for loop, then normally we would have to do

```
flag = 0
for i in [1,2,3]:
    if condition:
        flag = 1
        break
if flag == 0:
    do stuff
```

we can instead do

```
for i in [1,2,3]:
    if condition:
        break
else:
    do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think about it that: When the `break` statement is executed in the loop, the code inside the loop following the `break` statement will be ignored and the loop is finished

if the `break` statement is not executed, the code following the `else` statement will be executed after the loop is finished

Mateen Ulhaq and Lance Helsten gave a good example in here [Why does python use 'else' after for and while loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops)

```
for i in mylist:
    if i == theflag:
        break
    process(i)
else:
    raise ValueError("List argument missing terminal flag.")
```

and

```
flagfound = False
for i in mylist:
    if i == theflag:
        flagfound = True
        break
    process(i)

if not flagfound:
    raise ValueError("List argument missing terminal flag.")
```

I often use `else` statement to mark the last turn in for/while loop

Comment: I find it logically counter intuitive because in the python if else block use case.  Consider if mylist is true as in `if mylist:` the else is never executed. So IMO the reverse case is more in step with the language.  `for x in mylist`  should only reach the else block `if mylist` is also false to begin with.