# List with dictionary

Tags: python

Imagine that I have this list:

```
a=[ {'name':'John','number':'123'} , {'name':'Mike','number':'12345'} ,{'name':'Peter','number':'12'}]

name=input('insert your name')
number=input('insert your number')
```

If I want to have  3 scenarios: one where the name and number matches, the second where the name is correct but the number is incorrect and the last one where the name does not exist.

```
if {'name':name,'number':number} in a:
    print('okay')
else:
    if {'name':name} in a and {'number':number} not in a:
        print('user okay, but incorrect pass')
    else:
        print('No username')
```

This type of code will not work, right?
So how can I solve the second step (after the first else)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually write the code like this, making use of list comprehension. It seems more readable.

```
if name in [pos['name'] for pos in a]:
    if number == [dd for dd in a if dd['name'] == name][0]['number']:
        print('okay')
    else:
        print('user okay but incorrect pass')
else:
    print('No username')
```

Or alternatively, if you are ok with a `for` loop:

```
for dd in a:
    if name == dd['name']:
        if number == dd['number']:
            print('okay')
        else:
            print('user okay but incorrect pass')
        break
else:
    print('No username')
```

Note the `else` after the `for` loop: this construct it's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops).

The latter is more efficient, as it iterates over the list only once (and not all the list if a match is found).

Answer (score 2):

You could use `any` like so:

```
if {'name':name,'number':number} in a:
    print('okay')
elif any(entry["name"] == name for entry in a):
    print('user okay, but incorrect pass')
else:
    print('No username')
```

I also simplified your `else: if:` to use `elif:` instead.