# Python code to populate a list works, but similar code to populate a vector doesn't work in R

Tags: python, r, for-loop

Get a vector consisting of prime numbers as output from given input vector. Worked in Python, wherein I appended each prime number from the input list to an empty list, but not getting correct output in R

Python Code:

```
def get_prime(input_list):
    output_list = []
    for num in input_list:
        for i in range(2, num):
                if num%i == 0:
                    break
        else:   
            output_list.append(num)
    return output_list
```

Output:

```
get_prime([3,4,5,6,7,8])
[3, 5, 7]
```

R Code:

```
get_prime <- function(input_number_vector){
  prime = c()
  for(num in input_number_vector){
    for(div in 2:(num-1)){ if(num %% div == 0) break 
                           else prime = c(prime,num)
                                                   }
    }
  prime
}
```

Output:

```
x <- c(3,4,5,6,7,8)
> get_prime(x)
[1] 3 5 5 5 7 7 7 7 7
```

Expected Output:

```
3,5,7
```

Looks like the odd numbers: 3, 5, 7 are appended once for each modulus condition check. i.e. 3 once with divisor of 2, 5 thrice with divisors 2,3,4 and 7 with divisors 2,3,4,5,6. 
Could someone let me know where I am going wrong and if R works differently than Python in this regard.

Comment: The R code is simply not doing the same as the Python code. They are similar but not identical (the R code appends to the vector inside the inner loop).

Comment: You're updating the `prime` vector each time the remainder is non-zero. If you try with some odd non-prime numbers, this code will print the that number many times for as many numbers exceed the first divisor, starting from 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are obviously better ways to code this up but as far as debugging your code is concerned here are some observations.

`else` in Python code is outside `if` block whereas in R code you are presenting it in at the same level as `if`. Having `else` like this in [Python is permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops) whereas the same is not allowed in R. If you try to use the same thing in R, you will get an error. (by same thing I mean having `else` without an `if`).

Another point is to have check to add a number in `prime` only if it has exhausted the entire `2:(num-1)` . Incorporating these two changes we can write your function as

```
get_prime <- function(input_number_vector){
   prime = c()
   for(num in input_number_vector){
     for(div in 2:(num-1)){ 
       if(num %% div == 0) break 
     }
     if (div == num - 1)
        prime = c(prime,num)
     }
     prime
 } 

x <- c(3,4,5,6,7,8)
get_prime(x)
#[1] 3 5 7
```

Answer (score 1):

`for..else` is a construct pretty **unique to Python**. What you are saying that `if` we do not break in the `for`, we append. `R` has no such construct, and as such the `else` is matched with the `if`. You also seem to be interpreting the space ruling of the Python syntax to be the same here - it is again, a unique Python thing. Any other language I know which encounters an `if...else` will interpret them together Regardless of newlines/spacing between them, which is what you mahve have not expected.

The easiest way to do this without the special Python construct is to use a flag before the loop, `is_prime<-1`, and set it to 0 if you find it is not. Then **out** of the loop check `if(is_prime)`, and append if so. Amending the body of the outer loop results in:

```
is_prime<-TRUE
for(div in 2:(num-1)) {
    if(num %% div == 0) {
        is_prime<-FALSE
        break 
    }
}
if (is_prime) prime = c(prime,num)
```

Comment: R uses `TRUE` and `FALSE` for logical values (not `1` and `0`), and doesn’t use semicolons. Otherwise good explanation.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks I will edit.  It was just force of habit :).