# Can we have an ELSE statement without IF

Tags: python, if-statement

I recently noticed [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-print-all-prime-numbers-in-an-interval/) snippet of code to find `prime numbers` between a range of numbers. Let me put the code here as well -

```
start = 11
end = 25
for val in range(start, end + 1): 
   # If num is divisible by any number   
   # between 2 and val, it is not prime  
   for n in range(2, int(val/2)+1): 
       if (val % n) == 0: 
           break
   else: 
       print(val)
11
13
17
19
23
```

If the inner `for loop` is exhausted without getting `remainder` 0 for any of the divisors, then the said number is a `prime number`. In this case this `else`, *which doesn't even have its corresponding `if`*, gets executed thereby printing the prime number. But, in case we found a divisor which produces 0 as remainder, then we `break` from the inner `for` loop, but this time the `else` is not executed.

**My question:** What is this construct where we can have an `else` statement without its engendering `if` statement? Can anyone explain as to how this construct even works?

Comment: It's true that the `else` doesn't have an `if`, but that doesn't make it standalone. It's paired with the `for`, see the duplicate for a fuller explanation.

Comment: In this particular snippet, you could argue it could be seen as paired with the `if` inside the loop: if that `if` statement never evaluates to `True`, the `else` part is executed. It's not actually true, but it's another way to look at it.

Comment: Also (another) duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops

Comment: @9769953 Yeah, that part is fine. I would have implemented it exactly the way you are suggesting, but this "stand alone" `else` confounded me.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks a ton for refering me to this link. Now, I understand this concept.