# Is else outside for loop, if yes why else is not executing?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, indentation

```
numbers = [10, 20, 33, 55, 39, 55, 75, 37, 21, 23, 41, 13]

for num in numbers:
    if num % 2 == 0:
       print(num)
       break
else:
   print(num)
```

In the above code i do have `else` block corresponding to `for` loop and which is not getting executed. can someone guide me why it is not executing ?

Comment: Why did you remove the question from the question?

Comment: The "else" is executed only if the loop isn't exited by "break" or exception but normally.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: The question isn't clear. `else` is not outside the `for` loop, it's part of the `for` statement itself.

Comment: This script prints the first even number. If there are no even numbers, it prints the last odd number. Is that what it's supposed to do?

Comment: my question is , is else inside or outside for loop?

Comment: check my answer @Anuvicleo `else` is outside of the loop please read it completely

Comment: if else is outside for loop then it should execute right??

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops

Comment: the else will only execute if you didnt break from the loop, like @Deadpool said in his answer. I have also posted an answer with sample tests that hopefully explains the `for` and `else` construct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes the `else` block is corresponded to `for` loop, but it will execute only if `break` is NEVER executed. Since you have the even numbers in `numbers` list break is executed and which is why `else` is not executed

```
for num in numbers:
  if num % 2 == 0:
     print(num)
     break
else:
  print(num)
```

Try with this list `number=[11,22,33]`, `else` block will get executed, for more information 
[4.4. break and continue Statements, and else Clauses on Loops](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Python has different syntax where Loop statements may have an else clause

> Loop statements may have an else clause; it is executed when the loop terminates through exhaustion of the iterable (with for) or when the condition becomes false (with while), but not when the loop is terminated by a break statement. This is exemplified by the following loop, which searches for prime numbers:

Comment: i have edited the question, please can you answer again

Comment: @Anuvicleo This answers the question. The `else` block is only executed if there are no even numbers in the list.

Comment: is else outside or inside for loop?

Comment: Yes it is outside of the `for` loop please read my answer completely @Anuvicleo

Comment: why break statement is affecting 'else' from being executed since as you said 'else' is outside for loop

Comment: read the documentation that i pointed to, it is a valid syntax in python, you can have `else` block for `Loop statements` @Anuvicleo In your case that else is dedicated to above `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

There is no "if" for that else. I think you need something like this:

```
numbers = [10, 20, 33, 55, 39, 55, 75, 37, 21, 23, 41, 13]

for num in numbers:
    if num % 2 == 0:
        print(num)
        break
print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Indentaion seems to be wrong, try this.

```
for num in numbers:
    if num % 2 == 0:
        print(num)
        break
    else:
        print(num)
```

Comment: It depends on what it's supposed to do.

Comment: its perfectly valid for a `for` loop to have an `else` clause

Comment: Totally, but he seems to be more concerned about indentation.

Comment: This will print all the odd numbers up to the first even number, and then print that even number.

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to demonstrate this with varying tests. So a `for` loop can have an `else` block. the `else` block is only executed if the loop completed normally. I.E there was not `break` in the loop. if we create a function that takes a list and a divider. we can see that if the `if` condition is matched and we print then break, the `else` block is never run. Only if we run all the way through the loop without `break` then the `else` is executed

```
def is_divisable_by(nums, divider):
    for num in nums:
        if num % divider == 0:
            print(num, "is divsiable by ", divider)
            break
    else:
        print("none of the numbers", nums, "were divisable by", divider)

numbers = [1, 6, 3]
numbers2 = [7, 8, 10]
is_divisable_by(numbers, 2)
is_divisable_by(numbers, 7)
is_divisable_by(numbers2, 4)
is_divisable_by(numbers2, 6)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
6 is divsiable by  2
none of the numbers [1, 6, 3] were divisable by 7
8 is divsiable by  4
none of the numbers [7, 8, 10] were divisable by 6
```