# Python 3 how does the 'else' work in this loop

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, permutation

This piece of code generates the permutation, I'm interested to how the `else: return` at the end works.

```
all_str = []
def permu(iterable,r=None):
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    r = n if r is None else r
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = list(range(n))
    cycles = list(range(n, n - r, -1))
    all_str.append( tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r]))
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            cycles[i] -= 1
            if cycles[i] == 0:
                indices[i:] = indices[i + 1:] + indices[i:i + 1]
                cycles[i] = n - i
            else:
                j = cycles[i]
                indices[i], indices[-j] = indices[-j], indices[i]
                all_str.append( tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r]))
                break
        else: # here
            return
permu("abcde",4)
```

what is the `else` at the bottom referring to? I know that you can have an `if` in the loop and `else` outside the loop, but this doesn't seem to be the case as the `if` is already taken care of by an `else`.

When I remove the `else: return`, the function generates permutation endlessly in a repeating fashion.

I want to know this because I need to replicate this code in C++.

Any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: It's more clear to read the "for else" as "for finally". The else is executed if the for loop finishes correctly. [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops). In your example, it will return (exit the while) after for finishes.

Comment: @Raphael yes! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `else` statement of a for loop is executed if nobody explicitely executed a `break` from within the for loop
( Full explanation in the python documentation https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement )

so if you want to replicate this in C++
you had to set a variable that keeps track whether you quit the for loop via a break or just because the for loop finished.

I didn't write C for ages, so there might be tiny errors in my pseudo C code.

```
while(bla){
  int encountered_break = 0;
  for(bla;bla;bla){
      if (bla){
      } else {
          encountered_break = 1;
          break;
      }
  }
  if(!encountered_break){
      return;
  }
}
```

Comment: fixed some errors in previous comment (now deleted as wrong and redundant):

@Raphael Do you have an example of a code without `break`, that would __not__ call the `else` section of a for loop?

An example causing an exception within the for loop will just raise a normal exception so neither `else:` nor any code after the exception is executed.

Also after reading the documentation of the `for` loop (    https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement ) I don't see how I could __not__ enter the else section, except with a `break`.

Comment: strange: Whenever I get down votes I never get an explanation  (which would help me to improve the quality of my answer)

Added a link to the full documentation of the for loop in case this was the reason.

Answer (score 2):

the `else` clause of a for loop runs under a special circumstance: if the loop finishes without any disruption (in this case: `break`) the `else` clause will run, otherwise, it will be skipped. 
Namely, if the `else` related to the `if` is executed, the `else` of the `for` won't run.

Answer (score 1):

It's more clear to read the `for else` as `for finally`. The `else` is executed if the `for loop` finishes correctly. In your example, it will return (exit the while) after the `for loop` finishes.

In your example, if you remove the `else: return`, than the execution will always be inside the `while True`.

Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops).