# If Statment in Python while Scraping

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement, web-scraping, python-itertools

I want to add `if statement` there:

`if` website_link and phone is not found than write N,N

This Script is typing if website link is not found it type **N** and if phone is not found it type `N`

I Want Also Add This:

If Website And Phone is not found Type N,N

Here is my Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import csv
import pandas
import itertools

with open("sans.csv",'r') as s:
    s.read()

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

url = 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/konomama-san-francisco?osq=Restaurants'

driver.get(url)
website_link = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.text--offscreen__373c0__1SeFX+ .link-size--default__373c0__1skgq')

phone = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.text--offscreen__373c0__1SeFX+ .text-align--left__373c0__2pnx_')

items = len(website_link)
with open("sans.csv", 'a',encoding="utf-8") as s:
    for combination in itertools.zip_longest(website_link, phone):
         s.write(f'{combination[0].text if combination[0] else "N"}, {combination[1].text if combination[1] else "N"}\n')

driver.close()

print("Done")
```

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `else` to the `for` loop. It will run in case the loop doesn't when `website_link` and `phone` are empty

```
with open("sans.csv", 'a', encoding="utf-8") as s:
    for combination in itertools.zip_longest(website_link, phone):
        s.write(f'{combination[0].text if combination[0] else "N"}, {combination[1].text if combination[1] else "N"}\n')
    else:
        s.write('N, N')
```

For more info about `for - else` structure see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9980160/5168011).

Comment: Exactly the way I would have used. Could you add a brief explanation of how `for ... else ...` clause works in python as the asker seems to be starting with Python?

Comment: @Adirio This is a good [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9980160/5168011)

Comment: I do know what `for ... else ...` clause does, I was suggesting to add that info into the answer. The link is actually quite nice, I would include it in your answer.

Comment: @guy This is typing n in next line if something found

Comment: @HamzaLachi just add new line character `s.write('N, N\n')`

Comment: @Guy I Add This My Question Is for example if website and phone found it will write website and phone Error when it type phone and website it will insert new line and add N,N if website and phone Found

Answer (score 0):

may be he wants the iterator to iterate and check for `None` in `website_link` and `phone`

```
with open("sans.csv", 'a',encoding="utf-8") as s:
    for combination in itertools.zip_longest(website_link, phone):
         s.write(f'{combination[0].text if combination[0] else "N"}, {combination[1].text if combination[1] else "N"}\n')
         if(website_link == None) and (Phone == None):
               s.write('N,N')
```

Comment: If `website_link` or `phone` where `None` `itertools.zip_longest` would have thrown an exception. And they will never be `None` in any case.

Comment: @Guy You Are True

Comment: Yes, in that case we may simply use 'izip_longest' or 'zip' instead of 'zip_longest'. just let me know if it works.