# Trying to understand indents in Python

Tags: python

I am relatively new to python, and have been working on a problem to find the prime numbers between two inputs. I have a solution that works (helped somewhat by online searching too), but am unsure on why the `else` statement shown below should not be at the same tab setting as the `if` statement. If it is, though, it doesn't work correctly. Can anyone clarify this for me?

My code is here:

```py
n1 = int(input("Enter the lower number: "))
n2 = int(input("Enter the higher number: "))

for num in range(n1, n2 + 1):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, num):
            if num % i == 0:
                break
        else:
            print(num)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does python use 'else' after for and while loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops)

Comment: Have a look at this example in the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Comment: think of it this way.  you could have defined a variable `found = False` above you inner loop.  then when you have a % modulo 0 remainder you’d set `found = True` before `break`.  then, without that loop-else, you'd know it was a prime if found was still False at the end.  The loop-else allows you to skip tracking variable in these types of cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're seeing Python's (rather unique) [`for:else:` pattern](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/compound_stmts.html#for), to execute something when a `break` is not encountered within the `for` suite:

> When the items are exhausted, the suite in the `else` clause, if present, is executed, and the loop terminates.
>   A `break` statement executed in the first suite terminates the loop without executing the `else` clause’s suite. [...]