# Understanding the outcome a `FOR` loop with a nested `IF` statement

Tags: python, loops

I am learning Python currently. I wanted to get help to understand how the If and For function work when certain conditions don't get met.
I am trying to define a function that will determine the number of prime numbers starting from 2 till the input number.
For eg - count_primes(100) will give the output as 25 (total number of prime numbers between 0 and 100)

I wanted to increase the counter **i** by **1** only when the complete `for` loop for **range (2,item)** does not have any instances of n where the **item % n** (remainder of item divided by n) is equal to zero or item % n is not equal to zero for all n instances within the `for n in range (2,item)` loop.

**Broader question**: How do you write the code for cases where we might want to return a single variable based on the outcome of the entire for loop as in this case ?

My code is as follows -

```
def count_primes(num):
        i = 0

        for item in range (2,num):

            for n in range(2,item):
                if item % n == 0:
                    break

            i += 1

        return i
```

Thanks in advance to all who chose to share their feedback and guidance.

--

Kind Regards,
Nilotpal

Comment: You could set a flag in your inner `if` loop and increment `i` based on the value of the flag.

Comment: This might also be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this :

```
def count_primes(num):
    i = 0
    for item in range(num):
        if item <= 1:
            continue
        for n in range(2, item):
            if item % n == 0:
                break
        else:
            i += 1
    return i
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `else` with your `for` loop. 
The code block under `else` will be executed only when the `for` loop is exhausted, i.e - finished without breaking out.

```
for i in range(10):
# logic for each iteration
else:
# the code here will be executed  only if the loop finished 10 successful iterations
```