# Python Comparison using While Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning the basics of programming using Python and I am trying to compare a variable to another. Here's what I have:

```
code = "03"
count = 0

npw=str(input("Enter code: "))
while count != 2:
    if npw == code:
        print("Success")
        break
    else:
        print("incorrect")
        npw=str(input("Enter code: "))
        count += 1
print("Reached Maximum Tries")
```

I want the user to have 3 tries to guess the code, but upon trying 3 tries, the third one was not read. Also, when I entered the correct code, it also prints the "Reached Maximum Tries".
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: use a for loop instead. `for count in range(3)`

Comment: You print "Reached Maximum Tries" because it is outside the loop. It will always be printed no matter what happens inside the loop.

Comment: `str()` is unnecssary on `input()`.  `input()` returns a `str` already.

Comment: Thank you for all the help guys! I really appreciate the help. Now I am learning in the right direction.

Comment: `while count < 3:`?

Answer (score 0):

- You check if the code is correct before asking for the last time! Change the order around to fix that problem.
- You always print "Max". You can do that using `else`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops) for examples.
- Minor point: you don't need to convert strings to strings!

Final solution:

```
code = "03"

for count in range(3):
    npw = input("Enter code")
    if npw == code:
        print("Success")
        break
    print("Incorrect")
else:
    print("Max")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Ma'am! I am still learning the ropes and I find that this is challenging with my age (40) and my learning curve is not the same when I was young. :) I have been thinking too hard not knowing that using "For" instead of "While" will do the trick. Thanks again