# Compare 2 dictionary and extract the other values in python

Tags: python

I have a parent dictionary

```
parent = [
  {
    "user": "a@gmail.com",
    "type": "Product Team",
    "message": "Developer",
    "employeeId": 101
  },
  {
    "user": "b@gmail.com",
    "type": "Product Team",
    "message": "Developer",
    "employeeId": "102"
  }
]
```

My input is

`body = {"employeeId":102}`

My input will vary  for testing

`body = {"employeeId":101}`

`body = {"employeeId":103}`

I have search in parent dictionary and retrieve the `user` `employeeId` and `message` if it matches `employeeId`

- I need to iterate over the parent dictionary
- once I found the first match then i have to break out from the loop
- if not i need to continue the loop
- if success i need to return a dictionary
- if `employeeId` doesnot match in parent dict then it should say employeeId doesnot exist

My code is below

```
def noid():
    return "No ID"
def new_f():
    for conf in parent :
        if int(conf["employeeId"]) == int(body['employeeId']):
             user = conf['user']
             employeeId= conf["employeeId"]
             message = conf["message"]
             return {'user': user, 'employeeId': employeeId, 'message': message}
             break
        else:
            continue
        return noid()
new_f()
```

In my code only `employeeId:101` is working only for first element is working./ Only first dictionary getting success

Comment: `solution = list(filter(lambda x: x.get('employeeId',None)==str(body['employeeId']), parent))`

Comment: `int(parent ["employeeId"])` => this should be `int(conf["employeeId"])`     edit: fixed

Comment: can you please clarify your last sentence, what is your problem and the expected behavior ?

Comment: yes, only first dictinary is getting success

Comment: Your code works fine... I ran it with `body = {"employeeId":102}` and printed the user and `b@gmail.com` was printed....

Comment: if employeeId doesnot match in parent dict then it should return  employeeId doesnot exist

Comment: So add an `else` to the `for`, but this is not clear as to be the problem from your question. You are saying that it only works for `101` but it also works with `102` so please clarify your question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does python use 'else' after for and while loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops)

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You always return after the first iteration...

Comment: @Tomerikoo if success i need to return {dictionary} otherwise return "No ID"

Comment: Yes I understood that. But your `return` statement is unconditional in the body's loop which means you never get past the first dictionary. Please see my edit to the answer

Comment: added my code which is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
user, employeeId, message = [''] * 3 # define variables before loop
found = False
for x in parent:
  if int(x['employeeId']) == int(body['employeeId']):
    user = x['user']
    employeeId = x["employeeId"]
    message = x["message"]
    found = True
    break
if found:
  print(user, employeeId, message)
else:
  print("Not found!")
```

Comment: How is that different from the original code? Also you never used `x`. It should probably be `for conf in parent:`

Comment: if employeeId doesnot match in parent dict then it should return employeeId doesnot exist

Comment: You can actually remove the `if found` block. The `else` can be directly under the `for`

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a [`for/else` construct](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops):

```py
for conf in parent:
    if int(conf["employeeId"]) == int(body['employeeId']):
         user = conf['user']
         employeeId = conf["employeeId"]
         message = conf["message"]
         break
else:
    print("No ID found")
```

---

According to the edited question where the code is in a function, you can simply `return` which obviously breaks the loop, so no `else` is necessary:

```py
def new_f():
    for conf in parent:
        if int(conf["employeeId"]) == int(body['employeeId']):
             user = conf['user']
             employeeId= conf["employeeId"]
             message = conf["message"]
             return {'user': user, 'employeeId': employeeId, 'message': message}

    return "No ID"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def noid():
    return "No ID"
def new_f():
    flag = 0
    for conf in parent :
        if int(conf["employeeId"]) == int(body['employeeId']):
             flag = 1
             user = conf['user']
             employeeId= conf["employeeId"]
             message = conf["message"]
             return {'user': user, 'employeeId': employeeId, 'message': message}
             break
        else:
            return noid()
if flag = 0:
        return noid()
```