# A better way than this nested try-except statement?

Tags: python, try-except

I have this code that receives input of a country:

```
flag1 = input("Enter country 1: ")
   while not worked:
      worked = True
      try:
         code1 = pycountry.countries.get(name=flag1).alpha_2
      except AttributeError:
         try:
            code1 = pycountry.countries.get(official_name=flag1).alpha_2
         except AttributeError:
            print("Invalid Input. Visit --- for list of country names.")
            flag1 = input()
            worked = False
```

I am planning to add two more ways of inputting a country (by 2/3-letter codes) so I'll have 2 more try-except statements. Is there an easier, simpler way to do this check, without having to nest 4 of these statements?

Comment: What is the type of `pycountry.countries`?

Comment: What are the validation rules? Instead of calling different functions, you could check the input and call the appropriate function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what you need. no try-except included.

```
import pycountry
code_1 =''
while True:
  flag1 = input("Enter country 1: ")
  aux = pycountry.countries.get(name=flag1) or pycountry.countries.get(official_name=flag1)
  if aux ==None:
    print("Invalid Input. Visit --- for list of country names.")
    continue
  code1 = aux.alpha_2
  break
print(code1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following could work:

```
lookups = [
    lambda x: pycountry.countries.get(name=x).alpha_2,
    lambda x: pycountry.countries.get(official_name=x).alpha_2
]

flag1 = input("Enter country 1: ")

worked = False
code1 = None

while not worked:
    for lookup in lookups:
        try:
            code1 = lookup(flag1)
        except:
            continue
        
        worked = True
        break
    
    if not worked:
        print("Invalid Input. Visit --- for list of country names.")
        flag1 = input()
```

An alternative could be to use the fuzzy search capability of pycountry or the lookups as described [here](https://pypi.org/project/pycountry/), which allow you to search without specifying which field to search in. That may or may not be appropriate for your case.

```
pycountry.countries.lookup('de')
<pycountry.db.Country object at 0x...>
```

Comment: To match the original code, you need to break the loop if there was no exception

Comment: Correct, I've fixed that oversight

Comment: Now, by the way, you can remove the use of `worked` by changing the last `if` block to an `else` on the `for` loop ;)

Comment: Today I learned something :) I had no idea `for` loops could have an `else` clause. Though it would then need something extra to break out of the outer loop once an input has been accepted.

Comment: It's really neat. Here is the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) and here is [a SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops) on the matter

Comment: You could `break` after the `else` and put a `continue` inside it...