# Python is not able to compare a value to a list element

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, range

So I am relatively new to python, not sure what is wrong here? I am sure it is a basic thing that I am missing but not sure what it could be, below is the code to find a matching target to any of the numbers in the list, which should work according to me but doesn't.

```
def abc(target,list1):
    for a in list1:
        if a == target:
            return a
        else:
            return 0
def main():
    target = input("enter target")
    list1 = []
    n = int(input("Enter number of elements : ")) 
    for i in range(0, n): 
        ele = input() 
    list1.append(ele)

g = abc(target,list1)
print(g)

if __name__== '__main__':
    main()
```

Below is the output which obviously returns 0 as the code does not work:

```
Enter target7
Enter number of elements : 4
5
6
7
8
0
```

should it not return 7 as the value in the list matches the target

Comment: Your for loop returns either a or 0 based only on the first compare.

Comment: Thanks, understood

Comment: @SwatanShah--it's a great place for a [for/else loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops)

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, your logic in `abc()` is off.

This should work as expected:

```
def abc(target, list1):
    return target if target in list1 else 0


def main():
    target = int(input("enter target"))
    list1 = []
    n = int(input("Enter number of elements : "))
    for i in range(0, n):
        list1.append(int(input()))
    print(abc(target, list1))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
Enter number of elements : 4
5
6
7
8
7
```

Answer (score 0):

You had the wrong indentation:

```
def abc(target,list1):
    for a in list1:
        if a == target:
            return a
        else:
            return 0


def main():
    target = input("Enter target: ")
    list1 = []
    n = int(input("Enter number of elements: "))
    for i in range(0, n):
        ele = input(f"Enter element #{i+1}: ")
        list1.append(ele)

    g = abc(target,list1)
    print(g)


if __name__== '__main__':
    main()
```

```
Enter target: 2
Enter number of elements: 1
Enter element #1: 2
2
```