# Else block without if block in python

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, control-flow

I found the Python Code snippet online to print the range of the prime number but the **last else block** is making no sense to me as **it doesn't has corresponding if block**

**Note**
The Indentation of else block is intentional as it work correctly the way it is and i come up with this code after watching the tutorial on youtube at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KdiWcJscO_U

```
entry_value = int(input("Plese enter the starting value:"))
ending_value = int(input("Plese enter the ending value:"))
for i in range(entry_value, ending_value+1):
    if i>1:
        for j in range(2,i):
            if i%j == 0:
                break
        else:
            print("{} is prime number".format(i))
```

Comment: The indentation of this code is just wrong.

Comment: Indentation of this else statement is intentional i come up with this code from the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KdiWcJscO_U

Comment: Nothing wrong with the indentation, this is a good example of the rarely used for/else logic.

Comment: @jps I think the indentation is actually correct since `if i%j == 0` it's not a prime number. It just seems like a weird way to program that, kinda backwards.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does python use 'else' after for and while loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops)

Answer (score 6):

Python (and other languages) use an `else` block to specify code that runs only if the `for` loop was completed, and not broken out of.

In your code, `if i%j == 0` the loop will exit, but the else code will not be called.

Here is an example with comments:

```
for x in range(2,i):
    if i%j == 0:
        break #number is not prime so we break and don't call else
else:
    print("{} is prime number".format(i))
```