# Alignment of else: under if: in python

Tags: python, if-statement, break

I would like to understand why the following python code to find all prime numbers less than `n` works:

```
def prime(n):
    for q in range(2,n):
        for i in range(2,q):
            if q%i==0:
                print(q, "is not a prime")
                break
        else:
            print(q, "is a prime")
```

My problem is that I thought the else: should be aligned under the if: but it isn't in this code. I think the problem is that I do not understand well enough what the "break" does.

Comment: The shown code should lead to indentation error already on the first `for q ...` line.

Comment: Python also has `for-else`, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9979970/1639625)

Comment: It is mentioned here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Comment: Seems like an error-prone feature that could lead to many bugs. Why not use a different keyword?

Comment: Please refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please make sure that your [mcve] doesn't contain unrelated problems, a good example should be able to be copy and pasted directly to replicate the problem being asked about without the need for us to edit it.

Answer (score 3):

In Python, for loops can also have an `else:` block (see `for_stmt` in the [parser grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html#full-grammar-specification)).  The else block of a for loop is entered if the loop runs to completion without hitting any break statement.

In your case, the `break` is conditional upon `q % i == 0`, so the else block here means that no number in `range(2, q)` has satisfied this condition, i.e. that `q` has no divisors besides `1` and itself.

*Note: this primality test is very similar to a [code snippet from the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).*

Comment: wow, been coding python for a while but I never knew that for loops could have an else block! thanks for that answer