# How to let prime number print once in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, primes

My prime number finding code is trying all numbers so it will print the prime number a few times. Eg: 5/2 , 5/3, 5/4. So it will print 5 for 3 times.

```
def prime_number_generator(num):
    for n in range (1,num):
        for prime in range (2,n):
            if (n%prime) ==0:
                break
            else:
                yield n

number = input('Please input the number:') 
if number.isnumeric():
    num = int(number)
    if num <= 2:
        print('Number must be greater than 2') 
    else: 
        for prime in prime_number_generator(num):
            print(prime, end=', ') 
else: 
    print('Must be a positive integer')
```

Output with input as 27:

```
3, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11,
 11, 11, 11, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
15, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 
17, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 
19, 19, 21, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 
23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 25, 25, 25,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The Problem

In this function:

```
def prime_number_generator(num):
    for n in range (1,num):
        for prime in range (2,n):
            if (n%prime) ==0:
                break
            else:
                yield n
```

You are yielding `n` if it is not exactly divisible by `prime`. Here is an example for what happens when `n = 5`:

- First, `prime = 2`. `n % prime != 0`, so `n`, i.e, `5` is yielded
- Then, `prime = 3`. `n % prime != 0`, so `5` is, once again, yielded
- Then, `prime = 4`, `n % prime != 0`, so `5` is, once again, yielded
- Finally, `prime = 5`. `n % prime == 0`, so the loop is broken.

This process is then repeated with the next `n`

## How to fix

You can remove the `else` clause from the `if`, and add it to the `for` loop. This means that `n` will be yielded only if the `for` loop was not broken, that is, only if `n` is not divisible by any number between `2` and `n - 1`.

So you can rewrite your function like this:

```
def prime_number_generator(num):
    for n in range (1, num):
        for prime in range (2, n):
            if (n % prime) == 0:
                break
        else:
            yield n
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not your only problem. You are also (incorrectly) returning `15` as prime because you are immediately assuming that the number is prime if it can't be divided by 2 (the first iteration of your second `for` loop). Try this (note the indentation of the `else`):

```
def prime_number_generator(num):
    for n in range (2, num):
        for prime in range (2, n):
            if (n % prime) == 0:
                break
        else:
            yield n
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops) for an explanation of `for..else` construct in Python.